# Difference between toFixed() and toPrecision()?

Tags: javascript, rounding, precision

I'm new to JavaScript and just discovered `toFixed()` and `toPrecision()` to round numbers. However, I can't figure out what the difference between the two is.

What is the difference between `number.toFixed()` and `number.toPrecision()`?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

`toFixed(n)` provides `n` length after the decimal point; `toPrecision(x)` provides `x` total length.

Ref at w3schools: [toFixed](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) and [toPrecision](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toprecision.asp)

> **EDIT**:
> I learned a while back that w3schools isn't exactly the best source, but I forgot about this answer until I saw kzh's, uh, "enthusiastic" comment. Here are additional refs from Mozilla Doc Center [for `toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) and [for `toPrecision()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision). Fortunately for all of us, MDC and w3schools agree with each other in this case.

For completeness, I should mention that `toFixed()` is equivalent to `toFixed(0)` and `toPrecision()` just returns the original number with no formatting.

And of course, the *real* source of truth is the JS specification, which in this case is https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-number.prototype.toprecision

Comment: Bah, I posted this in July 2010, and I didn't learn about w3fools until this year. While fools is correct about some things, not _everything_ on schools is wrong. Thanks for pointing out that I need to update this post, though; will do it in a bit.

Comment: `toPrecision(x)` doesn't "provide `x` total length", it formats to a number of given significant digits.  For example, `0.0000022.toPrecision(1)` would return `0.000002`.

Comment: I just visited w3fools and was not convinced whatsoever. I don't even see any argument. All I see is an advertisement for two other sites.

Answer (score 74):

I believe that the former gives you a fixed number of decimal places, whereas the latter gives you a fixed number of significant digits.

```
Math.PI.toFixed(2); // "3.14"
Math.PI.toPrecision(2); // "3.1"
```

Furthermore, `toPrecision` will yield [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) if there are more integer digits in the number than the specified precision.

```
(Math.PI * 10).toPrecision(2); // "31"
(Math.PI * 100).toPrecision(2); // "3.1e+2"
```

EDIT:
Oh, and if you are new to JavaScript, I can highly recommend the book "[JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)" by Douglas Crockford.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain this behavior: `(0.004).toPrecision(3) //'0.000400'`. I doubt that 'gives you a fixed number of significant digits' is an appropriate explanation

Comment: @DmitryKoroliov I think it does explain this.  In your example, the digit '4' is the first significant digit, so when you request 3 significant digits, it must add two more, which in this case are both zeros

Answer (score 39):

Examples speak clearly:

```
var A = 123.456789;

A.toFixed()      // 123
A.toFixed(0)     // 123
A.toFixed(1)     // 123.5      round up last
A.toFixed(2)     // 123.46     round up last
A.toFixed(3)     // 123.457    round up last
A.toFixed(4)     // 123.4568   round up last
A.toFixed(5)     // 123.45679  round up last
A.toFixed(6)     // 123.456789
A.toFixed(7)     // 123.4567890
A.toFixed(8)     // 123.45678900
A.toFixed(9)     // 123.456789000
A.toFixed(10)    // 123.4567890000
A.toFixed(11)    // 123.45678900000

A.toPrecision()      // 123.456789 
A.toPrecision(0)     // --- ERROR --- 
A.toPrecision(1)     // 1e+2
A.toPrecision(2)     // 1.2e+2
A.toPrecision(3)     // 123
A.toPrecision(4)     // 123.5      round up last
A.toPrecision(5)     // 123.46     round up last
A.toPrecision(6)     // 123.457    round up last
A.toPrecision(7)     // 123.4568   round up last
A.toPrecision(8)     // 123.45679  round up last
A.toPrecision(9)     // 123.456789
A.toPrecision(10)    // 123.4567890
A.toPrecision(11)    // 123.45678900

// ----------------------
// edge-case rounding
// ----------------------
var B = 999.99;
B.toFixed(0)      // 1000
B.toFixed(1)      // 1000.0
B.toFixed(2)      // 999.99
B.toFixed(3)      // 999.990

B.toPrecision(0)  // --- ERROR ----
B.toPrecision(1)  // 1e+3
B.toPrecision(2)  // 1.0e+3
B.toPrecision(3)  // 1.00e+3
B.toPrecision(4)  // 1000
B.toPrecision(5)  // 999.99
B.toPrecision(6)  // 999.990

var C = 0.99;
C.toFixed(0)      // 1
C.toFixed(1)      // 1.0
C.toFixed(2)      // 0.99
C.toFixed(3)      // 0.990

C.toPrecision(0)  // --- ERROR ----
C.toPrecision(1)  // 1
C.toPrecision(2)  // 0.99
C.toPrecision(3)  // 0.990
```

Comment: Should include oddities like `999.9` `toPrecision(3)` -> `1.00e+3`. Which don't fit into the behavior the examples show.

Answer (score 11):

I think this is best answered with an example.

Let's say you have the following data:

```
var products = [
  {
    "title": "Really Nice Pen",
    "price": 150
  },
  {
    "title": "Golf Shirt",
    "price": 49.99
  },
  {
    "title": "My Car",
    "price": 1234.56
  }
]
```

You want to display each of these products with the title and formatted price. Let's try using `toPrecision` first:

```
document.write("The price of " + products[0].title + " is $" + products[0].price.toPrecision(5));

The price of Really Nice Pen is $150.00
```

Looks good, so you might think this will work for the other products as well:

```
document.write("The price of " + products[1].title + " is $" + products[2].price.toPrecision(5));
document.write("The price of " + products[2].title + " is $" + products[2].price.toPrecision(5));

The price of Golf Shirt is $49.990
The price of My Car is $1234.6
```

Not so good. We can fix this by changing the number of significant digits for each product, but if we're iterating over the array of products that could be tricky. Let's use `toFixed` instead:

```
document.write("The price of " + products[0].title + " is $" + products[0].price.toFixed(2));
document.write("The price of " + products[1].title + " is $" + products[2].price.toFixed(2));
document.write("The price of " + products[2].title + " is $" + products[2].price.toFixed(2));

The price of Really Nice Pen is $150.00
The price of Golf Shirt is $49.99
The price of My Car is $1234.56
```

This produces what you expected. There is no guess work involved, and there is no rounding.

Answer (score 6):

Just:

```
49.99.toFixed(5)
// → "49.99000"

49.99.toPrecision(5)
// → "49.990"
```

Answer (score 5):

Under certain circumstances, `toPrecision()` will return exponential notation, whereas `toFixed()` will not.

Comment: Actually, `toExponential()` is a [separate function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toexponential.asp).

Comment: @Lord Torgamus: According to my copy of *Javascript: The Definitive Guide*, toPrecision(precision) will use fixed-point notation if the *precision* arg is large enough to include all the digits of the integer part of the number. Otherwise, exponential notation is used.

Comment: In at least some cases, this is not correct: in my Firefox, with `a = 999999999999999934464;`, `a.toFixed(0)` returns `"1e+21"`. Perhaps a more accurate answer would be that toFixed() does not return exponential notation unless toString() does.

Answer (score 2):

`toFixed(fractionDigits?)` has been explained more or less accurately in other answers:

- it returns a string representation of the number with `fractionDigits` [amount] digits after the decimal point:

An example:

```
(-3).toFixed(1)     // '-3.0'
(-3).toFixed(0)     // '-3'
(-3).toFixed()      // '-3'
(-0.03).toFixed(1)  // '-0.0'
```

---

`toPrecision(precision?)` **has not been described correctly in the previous answers, so one should pay attention.** *Also I'd add a disclaimer, that I haven't been able to digest the spec on `toPrecision`, so the next points are based on the try and error approach of testing the implementation in Node.js. And these steps don't cover all corner cases like what if the number is NaN, or the precision arg is not integer, or is <1 or >100 etc. This is in order not to make the explanation cluttered as the spec seems to be.*

**Numbering of cases is preserved thru the list, despite cases may seem similar to other, they are required to demonstrate a particular behavior*

1. **it first represents the number in exponential notation with `precision`** being the number of digits in the significand, like

> Case 1: `0.000004` → precision = 3 → `400 * 10^-8`
> Case 2: `0.0000004` → precision = 3 → `400 * 10^-9`
> Case 3: `123` → precision = 1 → `1.23 * 10^2`
> Case 4: `153` → precision = 1 → `1.53 * 10^2`
> Case 5: `1234.56` → precision = 3 → `123.456 * 10^1`
> Case 6: `1234.56` → precision = 5 → `12345.6 * 10^-1`

2. **then it rounds the significand part**

> Case 1:  `400 * 10^-8` → `400 * 10^-8` (no fraction was present, no change)
> Case 2:  `400 * 10^-9` → `400 * 10^-9` (same reasoning as in case 1)
> Case 3: `1.23 * 10^2` → `1 * 10^2` (`1.23` was rounded to `1`)
> Case 4: `1.53 * 10^2` → `2 * 10^2` (`1.53` rounded to `2`)
> Case 5: `123.456 * 10^1` → `123 * 10^1` (rounded too)
> Case 6: `12345.6 * 10^-1` → `12346 * 10^-1` (rounded)

3. **then it produces a string representation** of the number following the rules:

**3a)** all digits from the significand in step 2 will be preserved

**3b)** Exponential notation is used if `precision` < the number of digits before the point (in 'normal', i.e. decimal representation)

> Case 3: `1 * 10^2` → `'1e+2'` (number is now `100`, 3 digits, precision is 1, exponent is used)
> Case 4:`2 * 10^2` → `'2e+2'`  (number is now `200`, 3 digits, precision is 1, exponent is used)
> Case 5:`123 * 10^1` → `'1.23e+3'`  (number is now `1230`, 4 digits, precision is 3, exponent is used; *note that the significand has preserved all digits from step 2*: `123` became `1.23`)

**3c)** Exponential notation is used if the number has the 0 integer part and the number of zeros right after the decimal point  and before the first significant digit (in 'normal' notation) is >5

> Case 2:  `400 * 10^-9` → `'4.00e-7'` (number is 0.0000004, it has the `0` integer part and there are >5 zeros after the decimal point, *note that the two zeros from* `400 * 10^-9` *were preserved*)

**3d)** Decimal notation is used, if the number has the 0 integer part and the number of zeros right after the decimal point <= 5 but the digits from the significand from step 2 will be preserved

> Case 1:  `400 * 10^-8` → `'0.00000400'` (the two zeros from the significand part have been preserved)

**3e)** Decimal notation is used, if `precision` >= the number of digits before the point in decimal representation

> Case 6: `12346 * 10^-1` → `1234.6` (the decimal form of the number in step 2 is 1234.6, precision is 5, number of digits before the decimal point is 4, the string uses decimal notation, all digits from the significand in step 2 were preserved)

```js
console.log((0.000004).toPrecision(3));
console.log((0.0000004).toPrecision(3));
console.log((123).toPrecision(1));
console.log((153).toPrecision(1));
console.log((1234.56).toPrecision(3));
console.log((1234.56).toPrecision(5));
```

Comment: Well, that might explain weirdness like `999.9` `toPrecisison(3)` coming out as `1.00e+3` instead of `999` or `1`....

How might one get around such things?

Answer (score 1):

For example , we consider the variable a as,
 var a = 123.45
 a.toPrecision(6)
The output is 123.450
 a.toFixed(6)
The output is like 123.450000 // 6 digits after decimal point

Answer (score 0):

Both `toPrecision()` and `toFixed()` are functions designed to format a number before printing it out. So they both return `String` values.

There is one exception. If you use these functions on a **negative** Number literal, due to operator precedence, a Number is returned. What this means is that `toFixed()` or `toPrecision()` will return a string first, and then the `-` minus operator will convert the string back to a Number as a negative value. Please see below for an example.

`toPrecision()` returns a `String` representing the Number object in fixed-point or exponential notation rounded to significant digits. So if you specify that you want a precision of 1, it returns the first significant number along with either scientific notation to indicate the powers of 10 or the previous 0's before its decimal point if the significant number is < 0.

```
const num1 = 123.4567;

// if no arguments are passed, it is similar to converting the Number to String
num1.toPrecision();   // returns "123.4567

// scientific notation is used when you pass precision count less than total
// number of digits left of the period
num1.toPrecision(2);  // returns "1.2e+2"

// last digit is rounded if precision is less than total significant digits
num1.toPrecision(4);  // returns "123.5"
num1.toPrecision(5);  // returns "123.46"

const largeNum = 456.789;
largeNum.toPrecision(2);  // returns "4.6e+2"

// trailing zeroes are added if precision is > total digits of the number or float
num1.toPrecision(9);  // returns "123.456700"

const num2 = 123;
num2.toPrecision(4);  // returns "123.0"

const num3 = 0.00123;
num3.toPrecision(4);  // returns "0.001230"
num3.toPrecision(5);  // returns "0.0012300"

// if the number is < 1, precision is by the significant digits
num3.toPrecision(1);  // returns "0.001"
```

`toFixed()` returns a `String` representing the Number object in fixed-point notation, rounded up. This function only cares about the decimal point numbers

```
const num1 = 123.4567;

// if no argument is passed, the fractions are removed
num1.toFixed();  // returns "123"

// specifying an argument means you the amount of numbers after the decimal point
num1.toFixed(1);  // returns "123.5"
num1.toFixed(3);  // returns "123.457"
num1.toFixed(5);  // returns "123.45670"
num1.toFixed(7);  // returns "123.4567000"

// trying to operator on number literals
2.34.toFixed(1);  // returns "2.3"
2.toFixed(1);     // returns SyntaxError
(2).toFixed(1);   // returns "2.0"
(2.34e+5).toFixed(1);  // returns "234000.0"
```

I mentioned above an exception where using these functions on negative Number literals will return a Number and not a String due to operator precedence. Here are some examples:

```
// Note: these are returning as Number
// toPrecision()
-123.45.toPrecision();  // returns -123.45
-123.45.toPrecision(2);  // returns -120
-123.45.toPrecision(4);  // returns -123.5
-2.34e+2.toPrecision(1);  // returns -200
-0.0456.toPrecision(1);  // returns -0.05
-0.0456.toPrecision(6);  // returns -0.0456

// toFixed()
-123.45.toFixed();  // returns -123.45
-123.45.toFixed(1);  // returns -123.5
-123.45.toFixed(4);  // returns -123.45
-0.0456.toFixed(1);  // returns -0
-0.0456.toFixed(6);  // -0.0456
```

Fun fact: there are signed zeroes as seen from `-0.0456.toFixed(1)`

See: [Are +0 and -0 the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223359/are-0-and-0-the-same)