# Differentiating +0 and −0

Tags: javascript

It turns out `+0 === -0` evaluates to `true` despite +0 and −0 being *different* entities. So, how do you differentiate +0 from −0?

There is a hack:

```
if (1 / myZero > 0) {
   // myZero is +0
} else {
   // myZero is -0
}
```

Can I do better?

Comment: Why do you need to know this?  (Not condescending... I am really curious!)

Comment: your solution seems reasonable. (+0 === -0) being true seems like an oversight in the language so I don't know how else you'll resolve it. I wouldn't expect it to come up frequently.

Comment: @evan, it's not an oversight, it's what IEEE 754 requires.

Comment: You don't need a function, just do this check: `if ( 1 / x > 0 ) { ...`

Comment: @Jason: I'm just playing around with the specs, and considering a bunch of thought experiments. These kind of bizarre things could potentially lead to difficult-to-find bugs. See one of my fears here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223517/function-given-strictly-equal-arguments-yielding-non-strictly-equal-results

Comment: @JasonGennaro - right now I'm writing my own `printf` in javascript and `%+f` specifier must distinguish between `+0` and `-0`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In ECMAScript 6 `Object.is` behaves like `===` except that it distinguishes positive and negative zeroes, and `Object.is(NaN, NaN)` evaluates to `true`. (See [here](http://addyosmani.com/blog/a-few-new-things-coming-to-javascript/) for a writeup.)

Chrome 24 supports `Object.is`.

Comment: there's also an alternative version for ECMAScript 5 at the end of [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) if you need it for old browsers

Answer (score 14):

This is still some kind of hack, but a look at the specs suggests this:

```
Math.atan2(0, -0) === Math.PI // true
Math.atan2(0,  0) === 0       // true
```

Comment: Which specs are you referring to? ECMAScript? (Not doubting, I just want to know...)

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Yes, the part of `atan2`.

Comment: Do you have a link by chance?

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. :) It's for my own edification. (Note, pimvdb's reference is found at http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.8.2.5)

Comment: It works but is x10 times slower on my chrome than `1/zero` test

Comment: This doesn't work with every number: `Math.atan2(0, -5e-324) === Math.PI` is true, yet `-5e-324 === -0` is false.

Answer (score 9):

According to [David Flanagan's book, p. 34](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_5_14?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=javascript+the+definitive+guide+6th+edition&sprefix=javascript+the%2Cstripbooks%2C147), dividing 1 by your zero will produce the corresponding infinity, which can then be used in an equality check:

```
1 / 0
> Infinity
1 / -0
> -Infinity
```

And here's the behavior of the equality comparisons of infinities:

```
Infinity === -Infinity
> false
Infinity === Infinity
> true
-Infinity === Infinity
> false
-Infinity === -Infinity
> true
```

Comment: This doesn't work with every number: `1 / -5e-324` results in `-Infinity`, yet `-5e-324 === -0` is false.

Comment: @TimothyGu What's your point?  The question specifically asks about +0 and -0, not about "every number".

Comment: Certainly true. My bad for forgetting the original question

Answer (score 4):

To check the negative zero, here is one simple solution.

```
function isNegativeZero(n) {
    n = Number( n );
    return (n === 0) && (1 / n === -Infinity);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This returns +0:

```
-0 + 0
```

This doesn't help to differenciate -0 and +0, but this helps in ensuring that some value is not -0.

```
1 / -0       => -Infinity  
1 / (-0 + 0) => Infinity
```

Comment: or you could use `Math.abs(-0)`.

Comment: This is very useful for me because I needed to specifically ensure positive zero but leave other signed numbers alone.

Answer (score 3):

As people seem stumped as to what the practical need for this would be: here is my use case...

I needed a solution to sort the columns of a table by their index. Click the `<th>` and invoke the sorter with [ordinal] for ascending and -[ordinal] for descending. The first column would give `-0` for descending or `0` for ascending.

So I need to differentiate between `+0` and `-0` and ended up here. The solution that worked for me is in the comment by  @Šime Vidas, but is hidden away somewhat.

```
// This comparison works for all negatives including -0
if ( 1 / x > 0 ) { }

1 / -0 > 0  // false
1 / 0 > 0  // true
1 / -99 > 0 // false
1 / 99 > 0 // true

// WRONG: this naive comparison might give unexpected results
if ( x > 0 ) { }

-0 > 0 // true
// Gotcha
```

Answer (score 1):

One straight option in **Node.js** is to use [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

```
var negZero = Buffer('8000000000000000', 'hex')

var buf = Buffer(8);
buf.writeDoubleBE(myZero);

if (buf.equals(negZero)) {
    // myZero is -0
} else {
    // myZero is +0
}
```

Also, you can easily browserify them by [buffer module](https://github.com/feross/buffer).

Comment: Same idea by using TypedArray: `isPosZero = x => !(new Uint8Array(new Float64Array([x]).buffer).some(Boolean))`

Answer (score 0):

As hinted at by Matt Fenwick, you could just do (using the var `zero`):

```
if(1/zero===Infinity) {
  // zero is +0
} else {
  // zero is -0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.sign()`

```js
console.log(Math.sign( 1 / +0 ));
console.log(Math.sign( 1 / -0 ));
```