# Negatives in underscore.js: why is _isEqual(0, -1 * 0) returning false?

Tags: javascript, integer, underscore.js

Using the javascript library [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) (v.1.3.1), I've reproduced the following on the mac in up-to-date Chrome (17.0.963.56) and in Firefox 7.0:

```
0 === -1 * 0
> true

_.isEqual(0, -1 * 0)
> false
```

This is surprising, at least to me.  I expected that two values for which `===` is true would result in `_.isEqual` also being true.

What's going on here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been put explicitly [in the source](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore.js):

```
function eq(a, b, stack) {
  // Identical objects are equal. `0 === -0`, but they aren't identical.
  // See the Harmony `egal` proposal: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:egal.
  if (a === b) return a !== 0 || 1 / a == 1 / b;
```

In fact, JavaScript does interpret `0` and `-0` [differently](http://es5.github.com/#x8.5), but you usually don't see this because `0 == -0` and `0 === -0`. There are only [a few ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223717/differentiating-0-and-0) to check for the difference.

Comment: Thanks!  Seems like a non-obvious design decision to me, since `===` just about always suits my needs fine.  But I get the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the source for the `eq` function [here](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js). `-1 * 0` is `-0`, not `0`, so `0` and `-0` aren't equal, according to `isEqual`.

Relevant line:

```
// Identical objects are equal. `0 === -0`, but they aren't identical.
// See the Harmony `egal` proposal: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:egal.
if (a === b) return a !== 0 || 1 / a == 1 / b;
```

<sub>I did know about this before, but it'll make for some interesting evil code.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

It's deeper than that. JavaScript uses IEEE double-precision floating-point numbers, and they have different representations for 0 and -0 (which could be important when you are dealing with limits and such). But normally you don't notice this because 0 === -0.