# Sorting an array that contains both positive and negative zero

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects example

```
var objects = [ 
    { first_nom: 'dave', value: '5'},
    { first_nom: 'roger', value: '-0'},
    { first_nom: 'pete', value: '+0' },
    { first_nom: 'pete', value: '-5' },
];
```

Sorting this by value would ideally reverse the two zeros.

I have tried the normal javascript/jquery and underscore sorts but they ignore the leading `-` or `+` and probably rightly so.

This is what I currently have (this sorts fine but ignores the + and -):

```
var chartData = _.sortBy(objects, 'value').reverse();
```

Is there anything else someone can recommend please?

Many thanks

Nev

Comment: You'll have to add it as a special case to the sorting function. Show what you have now and someone'll be able to tell how to change it.

Comment: Don't use strings as value, but just an int. Int's can be negative

Comment: @AndreasFurster, that still won't sort them properly as it will convert the signed zeros to 'normal' zeros and nothing will happen.

Comment: Are the signed zeros really necessary for what you want to do?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. A total pain

Comment: I don't have access or rather it's not easy to access the ACTUAL value before this formatting was applied so I'm left with this data

Comment: @Andy The double precision floating point format distinguishes between positive and negative zeros which is why `1 / 0` is `Infinity` whereas `1 / -0` is `-Infinity`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
var objects = [ 
    { first_nom: "dave",  value: "5"  },
    { first_nom: "roger", value: "-0" },
    { first_nom: "pete",  value: "+0" },
    { first_nom: "pete",  value: "-5" },
];

objects.sort(function (a, b) {
    var x = parseInt(a.value, 10);
    var y = parseInt(b.value, 10);

    if (x === 0 && y === 0)
        return 1 / x - 1 / y || 0;
    else return x - y;
});

alert(JSON.stringify(objects, null, 4));
```

The reason this works is because `1 / 0` is `Infinity` whereas `1 / -0` is `-Infinity`.

For example:

1. First case: `x = 0`, `y = 0`:

   ```
   1 / x = Infinity
   1 / y = Infinity

   Infinity - Infinity = NaN

   NaN || 0 = 0
   ```

   Hence the two numbers are left unsorted with respect to each other.
2. Second case: `x = -0`, `y = -0`:

   ```
   1 / x = -Infinity
   1 / y = -Infinity

   (-Infinity) - (-Infinity) = NaN

   NaN || 0 = 0
   ```

   Hence the two numbers are left unsorted with respect to each other.
3. Third case: `x = 0`, `y = -0`:

   ```
   1 / x = Infinity
   1 / y = -Infinity

   Infinity - (-Infinity) = Infinity

   Infinity || 0 = Infinity
   ```

   Hence `x` will come after `y`.
4. Third case: `x = -0`, `y = 0`:

   ```
   1 / x = -Infinity
   1 / y = Infinity

   (-Infinity) - Infinity = -Infinity

   -Infinity || 0 = -Infinity
   ```

   Hence `x` will come before `y`.

That's all that there is to it really.

---

**Edit:** To sort it in reverse order just swap `x` and `y` as follows:

```js
var objects = [ 
    { first_nom: "dave",  value: "5"  },
    { first_nom: "roger", value: "-0" },
    { first_nom: "pete",  value: "+0" },
    { first_nom: "pete",  value: "-5" },
];

objects.sort(function (a, b) {
    var x = parseInt(a.value, 10);
    var y = parseInt(b.value, 10);

    if (x === 0 && y === 0)
        return 1 / y - 1 / x || 0;
    else return y - x;
});

alert(JSON.stringify(objects, null, 4));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Nevnev You should accept the best answer to your question. Click on the tick mark next to the best answer.

Comment: You might want to edit your sample code to sort in the (reversed) order that the Question asks for.

Comment: If I wanted to add a secondary sort on first_nom how can I work that into your code above? @AaditMShah

Comment: PS this will be the last time I bother you :) @AaditMShah

Comment: @Nevnev Just change `return 1 / y - 1 / x || 0` to `return 1 / y - 1 / x || b.first_nom.localeCompare(a.first_nom)`; and change `return y - x` to `return y - x || b.first_nom.localeCompare(a.first_nom)`.

Comment: Brilliant. thank you. Sorry about bothering you with such trivial tasks. @AaditMShah

Answer (score 2):

You can special-case them, sorting as strings when both values are `0`:

```js
var objects = [ 
    { first_nom: 'dave', value: '5'},
    { first_nom: 'roger', value: '-0'},
    { first_nom: 'pete', value: '+0' },
    { first_nom: 'pete', value: '-5' },
];

var sorted = objects.sort(
  function(a,b) {
    if ((a.value == 0) && (b.value == 0))
      {
        return b.value.localeCompare(a.value);
      }
    else
      return b.value - a.value;
  }
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(sorted));
```

Results in:

```
[
  {"first_nom":"dave","value":"5"},
  {"first_nom":"pete","value":"+0"},
  {"first_nom":"roger","value":"-0"},
  {"first_nom":"pete","value":"-5"}
]
```

Comment: String comparison is probably not the best way to compare numbers.

Comment: @AaditMShah Of course it's not. But in this one (insane) case, where we need to treat `-0` and `+0` as different entities, it's not really that much weirder than relying on different versions of division-by-zero.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to convert a signed zero to some signed small value, for example:

```js
var objects = [ 
    { first_nom: 'dave', value: '5'},
    { first_nom: 'pete', value: '+0' },
    { first_nom: 'pete', value: '-5' },
    { first_nom: 'roger', value: '-0'},
];

  
convert = function(n) {
  if(n == '-0') return -Number.EPSILON;
  if(n == '+0') return +Number.EPSILON;  
  return parseInt(n);
}
  
objects.sort(function(a, b) {
  return convert(a.value) - convert(b.value);
});
  

document.write(JSON.stringify(objects));
```

To do that in a pure numeric way, utilize the fact that

```
Math.atan2(0, -0) === Math.PI 
Math.atan2(0,  0) === 0
```

(see [Differentiating +0 and -0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7223717/989121))

```js
var objects = [ 
    { first_nom: 'dave', value: '5'},
    { first_nom: 'roger', value: '-0'},
    { first_nom: 'pete', value: '+0' },
    { first_nom: 'pete', value: '-5' },
];

objects.sort(function(a, b) {
  a = parseInt(a.value);
  b = parseInt(b.value);
  return (a || b) ? (b - a) : (Math.atan2(0, a) - Math.atan2(0, b));
});
  
document.write(JSON.stringify(objects));
```

Comment: This isn't a safe assumption. As soon as you add `{ first_nom: 'greg', value: '-0.000000009' },` you start to see the problem with going down this path.

Comment: @DRobinson: very insightful. I can't imagine how I missed that.

Comment: @DRobinson & georg - Why exactly? I don't get it