# Why does -0 exist?

Tags: javascript, math

While experimenting with JavaScript.  I was testing around with some odd little code snippets, here are a few of my findings (to help understand how I came upon `-0`),

While doing `+[]` in console, this returns `0`.  I'm not sure why, but it does.
So, this implies the positive of a array is `0`..

After doing so, I got curious and tried the following:

```
console.log(-[]);
```

And this returns `-0`...

What is the point of -0? 0 and -0 both hold no value, so the negative is really unnecessary...  Or is it? Perhaps JavaScript has a purpose for -0?

Adding onto that.  I cannot find any other way to reproduce `-0` other than using `-0` itself, or using `-[]`...

---

Some other weird findings, furthing my question of `-0`

```
(-0) + (-0) = 0
(-0) - (-0) = -0
(-0) * (-0) = 0
(-0) / (-0) = NaN // of course
```

Comment: `-0 < 0` -> 
`false`; 
`-0 == 0` -> 
`true`;
`-0 === 0` ->
`true`

Comment: it's a legacy thing, i wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: Also found this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223717/differentiating-0-and-0

Comment: +[] ==0 because "+" forces a number, and wanting a number from an array goes through the array's toString methods, which is a blank string, and the number equiv of a blank string is 0.

Comment: I'm asking `why does it exists`, not the difference.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero#Scientific_uses

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks for that, now that does seem useful. 
Math.round(-0.3)
//outputs -0
Math.round(0.3)
//outputs 0
Useful to know from which side I rounded to 0.

Comment: The irony of my username at this point.  Xero learns Zeros

Comment: when God and Brendan created JS in 6 days, they split up the workload, and Brendan, human to a fault, nibbled on the forbidden fruit of C knowledge. We mortals forever suffer because of his original sin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript uses [IEEE 754 standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7223395/4161269) to represent numbers. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_zero):

> **Signed zero** is zero with an associated sign. In ordinary arithmetic, −0 = +0 = 0. However, in computing, some number representations allow for the existence of two zeros, often denoted by **−0 (negative zero)** and **+0 (positive zero)**. This occurs in some signed number representations for integers, and in most floating point number representations. The number 0 is usually encoded as +0, but can be represented by either +0 or −0.
>
> The IEEE 754 standard for floating point arithmetic (presently used by most computers and programming languages that support floating point numbers) requires both +0 and −0. The zeroes can be considered as a variant of the extended real number line such that 1/−0 = −∞ and 1/+0 = +∞, division by zero is only undefined for ±0/±0 and ±∞/±∞.

From this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7223395/4161269)

Comment: Why is it present? What use does -0 serve?

Comment: like my mom answered for questions with unimportant answers: "it's there to make little boys ask why it's there"

Answer (score 2):

It's to help determine what happens when you divide by it.

If you divide by `+0`, you get `+Infinity`. If you divide by `-0`, you get `-Infinity`. (For nonzero numerators, of course).

Comment: I'm curious, why is it present? What's a use case for it?

Comment: I am asking the use case for -0. Where does it come up? How can I use it in practice?

Comment: @Aravind, as said in my question, the only placed I could find it come up is when using it directly (`-0`), or the negative of an array (`-[]`).  I'm still wondering what it's for though, why does it not all round out to `+0` or `0`?

Comment: @JesseSielaff: Sure, this is a use case. The use case of rounding to 0 from either side seems more compelling of a use case for signed zero.