# Javascript returns -0

Tags: javascript

I was trying out a simple arithmetic on console where I tried to multiply 0 with -1. Interestingly, I got a -0 as answer, instead of 0.

Screenshot:

[image]

Can anyone explain these results?

Comment: I believe he tried it on the developer console

Comment: No code.. Happened while trying in the console.

Comment: `0 === -0` is *true* anyways. hmmm, this looks like a webkit console. i'm interested in what other consoles have to say

Comment: It still violates the fundamental thought that 0 is neither positive nor negative

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223359/are-0-and-0-the-same

Comment: This question explains this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223359/are-0-and-0-the-same

Comment: @Yoshi - 
I believe I need not delete this question as per the post - [link]http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled. 

Request you to merge this post wherever necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript uses IEEE 754 as mentioned above and also,

> The IEEE 754 standard for floating-point arithmetic (presently used by
>   most computers and programming languages that support floating point
>   numbers) requires both +0 and −0. Real arithmetic with signed zeros
>   can be considered a variant of the extended real number line such that
>   1/−0 = −∞ and 1/+0 = +∞; division is only undefined for ±0/±0 and
>   ±∞/±∞.
>
> Negatively signed zero echoes the mathematical analysis concept of
>   approaching 0 from below as a one-sided limit, which may be denoted by
>   x → 0−, x → 0−, or x → ↑0. The notation "−0" may be used informally to
>   denote a small negative number that has been rounded to zero. The
>   concept of negative zero also has some theoretical applications in
>   statistical mechanics and other disciplines.
>
> It is claimed that the inclusion of signed zero in IEEE 754 makes it
>   much easier to achieve numerical accuracy in some critical problems
>   (http://people.freebsd.org/~das/kahan86branch.pdf), in particular
>   when computing with complex elementary functions.

http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/06/15/why-computers-have-signed-zero/

Answer (score 5):

[Under the IEEE standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

> Signed zero is zero with an associated sign. In ordinary arithmetic,
>   −0 = +0 = 0. However, in computing, some number representations allow
>   for the existence of two zeros, often denoted by −0 (negative zero)
>   and +0 (positive zero). This occurs in some signed number
>   representations for integers, and in most floating point number
>   representations. The number 0 is usually encoded as +0, but can be
>   represented by either +0 or −0.

Comment: Oh.. but is it just the way it is? Or can we lose the -0?

Comment: Its part of the standard for the comparison of x === y.. look here: http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.9.6

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is using IEEE-754, which has both positive and negative zeros.

Comment: Interesting.. where do we find the use for negative zeros?

Comment: I believe there is no important use - it's just a side-effect of the encoding used.

Comment: as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27074403/704944), one possible reason is so divison by zero can differentiate between -∞ and + ∞

Comment: @Jeremy Ah I see, interesting.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript uses IEEE 754 standard floating point number system. This system has both [positive and negative zeros](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Special_values) though they are equal when comparing. It has also positive and negative infinity and "not a number" values.