# Result of -0 subtracted from +0

Tags: javascript

I came across a statement *"If -0 is subtracted from +0, the result is -0"* in a JavaScript book published in year 2012.

However, when I compute `+0 - (-0)` in browser, it returns `0` instead of `-0`. I would like to know whether there is a change in ECMAScript since then or is it just simply an error/typo in the book.

If what the book mentioned is true, I would like to hear explanation and elaboration on this part.

Book: Professional JavaScript for Web Developers, 3rd Ed. by Nicholas C. Zakas (Chapter 3 - pg 63)

Comment: I don't understand why you need -0 or +0. Will it have any implications on the calculation as 0 is just 0 how can it be negative or positive.

Comment: even if it is internally right, it makes no sense, bacause you can not display it.

Comment: What book are you talking about? And which chapter?

Comment: you may have a look [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=KW9G9rdlStIC&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=If+-0+is+subtracted+from+%2B0,+the+result+is+-0&source=bl&ots=4XZSWIZWWt&sig=XRPKN-eUsHgJwzqDlVwNrBsOUeE&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGjerBtrXRAhUBGCwKHU72Dc0Q6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: @Ryan: TIL. Also I did `-0 + +0` instead of `-0 - +0`, which didn't help...

Comment: @RAJATHEVAR: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27074330/218196

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The book is incorrect.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-applying-the-additive-operators-to-numbers) Maybe it meant `-0 - +0`. From 12.7.5:

> - The sum of two negative zeroes is −0. **The sum of two positive zeroes**, or of two zeroes of opposite sign, is +0.

> Given numeric operands a and b, it is always the case that **a–b produces the same result as a +(–b)**.

and [12.5.0](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-unary-minus-operator):

> The unary - operator converts its operand to Number type and then negates it. Negating +0 produces −0, and **negating −0 produces +0**.

Also, I skipped to another random page in the book and found this:

> ### Comma Operator
>
> The comma operator allows execution of more than one operation in a single statement, as illustrated here:
>
> ```
> var num1=1, num2=2, num3=3;
> ```

which is not an instance of the comma operator. Two for two; get a refund.

Comment: While the documentation says the sum of two negative zeroes is -0, is there any feasible way to proof since the browser (chrome in my case)  display 0 for the above computation.

Comment: Yes, `1 / 0; //=> Infinity`.  `1 / (-0) //=> -Infinity`.  So you can check.

Comment: @whyyie `(-0) + (-0)` displays `0`?

Comment: I am still wondering where negative infinity  can be useful in real life