# Is there any way to compare negative 0 ie. -0 which is returned from Math.sign(-0)?

Tags: javascript

I'm using JavaScript `Date()` utility in my code to get the today's tasks by comparing two different dates.

```
otApp.TaskPanelUtils.getDaysDiff = function(task)
    {
        var current = new Date();
        var taskDueDate = new Date(task.unformattedDueDate())
        return Math.trunc((current.getTime()-taskDueDate.getTime())/otApp.TaskPanelUtils.oneDay);
    }

var daysDiff = otApp.TaskPanelUtils.getDaysDiff(taskItem);

if(daysDiff==0 && Math.sign(daysDiff)==0)
{
    tempItems.push(taskItem);
}
```

The above code is working even if I get "-0" *negative 0* as result of `getDaysDiff()`.

I want to fill `tempItems` only in case of positive "0".

`Math.sign(-0)` will return -0, then how come comparision with "-0" or -0 is not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differentiating +0 and -0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223717/differentiating-0-and-0)

Comment: You really should choose one question. Either "is there a way" or "how come it is not working".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are +0 and -0 the same?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223359/are-0-and-0-the-same)

Comment: Are you even getting -0 returned value from `getDaysDiff` method?

Comment: Hi @gurvinder372, Yes I'm getting -0 from getDaysDiff, as I'm truncating -0.9898 all those to -0.

Comment: So, you want to push those items for whom result is positive? does the actual daydiff matter to you?

Comment: Yes, I want to put only positives in a specific situation.. In this scenario I want to put items for which  daysDiff() is positive zero..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The above code is working even if I get "-0" negative 0 as result of
>   getDaysDiff().

Because `0` and `-0` evaluate to `0`.

```
Math.sign(-0) == Math.sign(0) //outputs true

0 == -0; //outputs true

0 === -0 //outputs true

String(-0) //outputs "0"
```

**Edit:**

I would suggest to simplify/modify the function so that it returns a boolean

```
otApp.TaskPanelUtils.getDaysDiff = function(task)
{
    var current = new Date();
    var taskDueDate = new Date(task.unformattedDueDate())
    return ((current.getTime()-taskDueDate.getTime())/otApp.TaskPanelUtils.oneDay) > 0;
}
```

And use it as

```
if(otApp.TaskPanelUtils.getDaysDiff(taskItem))
{
    tempItems.push(taskItem);
}
```

Comment: Hi @gurvinder372, Math.sign(-0) will return -0 and Math.sign(0) will return 0, according to the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign, how to consume Math.sign(-0) for comparing negarive zero.

Comment: @RajuPutchala `Object.is(0,-0)` should give `false`. However, I don;t think you need to do that. Just return true/false from getDiff method if value < 0.

Comment: Hi @gurvinder372, the above suggested code is working fine..thanks you

Comment: @RajuPutchala Glad to help, Please accept and upvote the best answer that has helped you http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work