# How to distinguish -0 and 0 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The strict equality operator identifies `0` and `-0` as being equal.

```js
console.log(0 === -0) // true
```

... so is [`Math.sign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign) the only way to distinguish these values?

Comment: `Object.is(-0, 0) === false`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differentiating +0 and -0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223717/differentiating-0-and-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `Object.is`:

```js
const num1 = 0;
const num2 = -0;
console.log(Object.is(num1, num2));
console.log(Object.is(num1, num1));
```