# Falsy? How does the && operator cause a 0 to return 0 rather than NaN?

Tags: javascript, return-value, nan, return-type

I read that sometimes the && operator is used to "short circuit" JavaScript into believing that a return value of 0 is 0 and not NaN because 0 is a falsy number in JavaScript.  I've been looking around to figure out what all this means.  Can someone explain it to a layman?

For example:

```
function sign(number) {    
    return number && number / Math.abs(number); }
```

Will return 0 if `number` is 0.

Comment: Why would a return value of 0 be NaN?

Comment: provide us please source of your informations

Comment: @KerrekSB To understand what he's asking, read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624920/number-sign-in-javascript/7624961#7624961

Comment: Basically, if `number` is `0`, then it will evaluate to `false`, so the `&&` operator will *short-circuit* and immediately "return" `0`, without evaluating its second operand, which would produce `NaN` since `number` is `0` and `0/0` is `NaN`.

Comment: I see now. This was a very poorly constructed question before the edit.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Ooops, brain fart.

Comment: This is going to sound a little silly, but I'm not a math wiz, really.  I thought 0/0 was "unidentified".  I've heard of people arguing against that for special and complex cases, but wouldn't "unidentified" be a more reasonable return value?  It's still NaN, but surely there would be cases where unidentified would be more useful than NaN.

Comment: @Kerrek That's just the nature of questions.  Without knowing the answer to a question, it's difficult to ask a question that speaks to the answer.  It's hard to know if answerers are going to understand, or if they will need additional information, or whatever.  Thanks for helping me find the right question.

Comment: @CokeChristopher: Well, perhaps, but you should strive to provide sufficient *context* for your question in any case. If you just say, "I heard a rumour about C++, is it true?", then it's hard for others to know what's going on in your mind. Anyway, I guess we've figured it out now :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, the boolean operators `&&` and `||` don't necessarily return a boolean. Instead, they look at the "truthiness" of their arguments and might short circuit accordingly. Some values like `0`, the empty string `""` and `null` are "falsy".

Short circuiting just means skip the evaluation of the right hand side of an expression because the left hand side is enough to provide the answer.

For example: an expression like `var result = 100 / number;`  will give you `NaN` when `number = 0`, but:

```
var result = number && 100 / number;
```

Will give you `0` instead of a `NaN` since `0` is falsy. In a boolean context `false && anything` is `false`, so there's no point in evaluating the right hand side. Similarly:

```
// supposed msg is a potentially empty string
var message = msg || "No message";
```

Will give you `msg` if the string `msg` is not empty (truthy) since `true || anything` is `true`. If `msg` *is* empty, it gives you `"No message instead"`.

Comment: Oh.  So, I guess the reason you use && instead of || is to prevent the program from moving forward with the check in the event of 0, but to keep it moving forward in the event of 1.  Sweet.  I totally understand, now.  Sorry I didn't give the check out earlier.  I was at work. :D

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like an answer that I saw earlier, but cannot find now (a link would be helpful), but you've got the wrong end of the stick here.

Given a situation like:

```
foo = 0 ;
bar = foo && 2 / foo;
```

On line two, foo will be evaluated. It is `0` and therefore a false value. The left hand side of `&&` (`foo`) will be returned and assigned to `bar`.

Now if we have `foo = 1`:

```
foo = 1 ;
bar = foo && 2 / foo;
```

Again, `foo` will be evaluated. It is a true value, so the right hand side of `&&` will be evaluated and returned. `2 / foo` is `2` so `2` is assigned to `bar`.

"Short circuit" just means that as soon as part of `&&` fails then it returns the part the failed without evaluating anything to the right.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you mean, however, it's not.

```
var some_bool = (func_a() && func_b());
```

Now, when func_a returns false, func_b indeed doesn't get called. However, when it returns NaN (which is, just like 0, equal to false) it still returns false!