# Enumerate tables and list names

Tags: excel, office-js

I'm working on some code, mostly just playing around, with the Office-js API (v1.1), trying to do some things. I can take code examples and run them just fine, but I don't know Javascript well enough to know what I'm doing.

I took an example of enumerating tables and am trying to add some things to it, but it's not working and I don't know why. Can anyone help me out here?

The code:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {

    var tables = ctx.workbook.tables;
    var tableNames = ctx.workbook.tables.load("name");

    return ctx.sync().then(function() {

        console.log("Tables in workbook:");

        if (tables.count = 0) {
            console.log("No tables found");

        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < tableNames.items.length; i++)
            {
                console.log(i + ": " + tableNames.items[i].name);
            }
        }
        console.log("------------------------");
    });

}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

In the console log I get this message:

```
Tables in workbook: 
TypeError: Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode
```

I'm basing this off code found here: http://officesnippetexplorer.azurewebsites.net/#/snippets/excel (select 'Table', and snippet 'Get tables in workbook'). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Zack Barresse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you mean to change `tables.count`, do you?

That's what the error is telling you - you have:

```
 if (tables.count = 0) {
```

but you really wanted:

```
 if (tables.count == 0) {
```

The first tries to set `tables.count` to `0`, the second tests if `tables.count` is equal to `0`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! That indeed worked just fine.

As a follow-up question (I can post a new one if need be, just let me know if that is the nettiquette 'round these parts), how would I format the index number being posted to the console log? For example, I want it always formatted with two digits.

I also see it is zero-based, which I'll need to find how to add a number to it lol.

Comment: Google is your friend for that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043026/javascript-format-number-to-have-2-digit is just the first link I found when searching "javascript format number" (taking google's suggestion of adding "to 2 digits" to my query).  Programming languages are good at adding one number to another; you should find a programming tutorial you like to learn more about that.