# typescript date formatting not working

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to get a date for mat like "2018-05-17T08:09:02", but when I tried below code I get "2018-05-17T8:9:2"
can some one help to get "2018-05-17T08:09:02" , this format

```
 let d = new Date();
console.log("date>> "+d.getFullYear() + "-" + ((d.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0' : '') +
 (d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d.getDate() + "T" +( d.getHours() )+ ":"+ d.getMinutes() + ":"+ d.getSeconds());
```

Comment: don't you simply want `new Date().toISOString()`? (it may have extra `.000Z` at the end that can be removed manually)

Comment: Using TS with AngularJS? Are you sure you don't wanna have this tagged as Angular (Angular 2+)?

Comment: I got it now  let d = new Date();
    console.log("KK"+d.getFullYear() + "-" + ((d.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0' : '') +
     (d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d.getDate() + "T" +('0' + d.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [How to format numbers by prepending 0 to single-digit numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8043061/6627660)

Your desirable answer is

```
let d = new Date();
console.log("date>> "+d.getFullYear() + "-" + ((d.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0' : '') +
 (d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d.getDate() + "T" +("0" + d.getHours()).slice(-2)+ ":"+ ("0" + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2)  + ":"+ ("0" + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2));
```

But as @Aleksey Solovey already mentioned in the above, I also recommand to use `d.toISOString().slice(0,-5)`.