# How to use NumberFormat in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

I'd like my countdown timer to show double digits, like "53:00" instead of "53:0". Not sure what's going wrong here? Thank you!

```
function convertSeconds(s) {
    var min = Math.floor(s / 60);
    var sec = s % 60;
    return nf(min, 2) + ':' + nf(sec, 2);
  }
```

Comment: Well that depends on whatever `nf()` is - you need to add that code to your question.

Comment: Thought that was numberformat? Do I need to make it its own function and refer to that with nf? What extra code do you expect to see? Srry, new to coding. Thanks for your time!

Comment: If your code works without errors then there is an `nf()` function written  somewhere - in a library you have included for example, its not a built in part of JavaScript.

Comment: `nf` is not a built-in Javascript function, you will need to show where it's defined, otherwise it's impossible to tell what it is and what it does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format numbers by prepending 0 to single-digit numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043026/how-to-format-numbers-by-prepending-0-to-single-digit-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

To pad zeroes you can do

```
function nf(num, places) {
  var s = '0' + num;
  return s.slice(places * -1);
}

function convertSeconds(s) {
  var min = Math.floor(s / 60);
  var sec = s % 60;
  return nf(min, 2) + ':' + nf(sec, 2);
}
```

Should get you what you want

Comment: There must be an nf() somewhere in your code stack, I would the code above with a different name as nf()'s current behavior/dependencies are unknown.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) to make sure a string is a certain length. If it's not it will pad it with whatever you want. In this case `0`:

```js
const nf = (n, c) => n.toString().padStart(c, '0');

function convertSeconds(s) {
  var min = Math.floor(s / 60);
  var sec = (s % 60)
  return nf(min, 2) + ':' + nf(sec, 2);
}

console.log(convertSeconds(64))
console.log(convertSeconds(119))
```

Not sure if you want to pad the minutes of not.

There is also the [`Intl.NumberFormat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) which has an option for minimum digits (though this seems like overkill for this):

```js
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2}).format(2));

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2}).format(59));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `nf()` function should be like this:

```
function nf(num){
    if(num < 10){
        return "0"+num;
    }
    return num;
}

console.log(nf(7));
// 07
console.log(nf(11));
// 11
```

Comment: You don't  need to convert to a string for the condition. `return n <= 9 ? '0' + n : n;` will be a slightly shorter way…

Answer (score 1):

If by `nf()` you mean a function that formats a `Number` as `string` of given digits, this can be an implementation of it:

```
function nf(number, digits) {
  var res = number.toString();
  while (res.length < digits) {
    res = "0" + res;
  }
  return res;
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function convertSeconds(s) {
  var min = Math.floor(s / 60);
  var sec = s % 60;
  return nf(min, 2) + ':' + nf(sec, 2);
}

function nf(number, digits) {
  var res = number.toString();
  while (res.length < digits) {
    res = "0" + res;
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(nf(4,2));
```