# Month in dropdown selection not in proper sequence

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I need a dropdown selection for expiry month [Jan, Feb....Dec] with values[01(Jan),02(Feb),03,.....12] for each option respectively.
I have used jquery.

But it shows 
October 10
November 11
December 12
January 01 .....so on.

I need January first.

```
  var parent = $('#main_div');
  var line_segment = $('<div>');
  var line_segment_nobackground = $('<div>');
  var row_wrapper = $('<div>',{'class':'row_wrapper_leftmargin'});
  var D_segment = line_segment.clone();
  var D_wrapper = row_wrapper.clone();
  var D_word = $('<div>',{ 'class':'segment_text_P text_align 
         padding_top_5', text:'Expiry Month' });
  var D_divider = $('<div>',{ 'class':'segment_5 text_calign padding_top_5', text:':' });
  var D_field = $('<select>', { 'class':'select_AccL', id:"month" });
  var data = {
    '01': 'January',
    '02': 'February',
    '03':'March',
    '04':'April',
    '05':'May',
    '06':'June',
    '07':'July',
    '08':'August',
    '09':'September',
    '10':'October',
    '11':'November',
    '12':'December'
}   

for(var val in data) {
    $('<option />', {value: val,text: data[val]}).appendTo(D_field);
}

//or wherever it should be

   D_wrapper.append(D_word);
   D_wrapper.append(D_divider);
   D_wrapper.append(D_field);
   D_segment.append(D_wrapper);
   parent.append(D_segment);
```

Comment: I believe this is because some browsers order object keys numeric-first. So 10 is put before 01, which is seen as non-numeric. I suggest [keeping all keys numeric](https://jsfiddle.net/jx6yz93v/) or using an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elements order in a "for (… in …)" loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop)

Comment: Use array to store them

Comment: I think it would be helpful to offer a little explanation of the problem and why you chose your solution. The expertise of a 140k+ member could be invaluable to this and future readers.

Comment: @showdev I have edited my answer.

Comment: @kritika555 Thanks for that! Sorry, I was referring to charlietfl but forgot to tag that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>   var data = [];
>   data['1'] = 'January - 01';
>   data['2'] = 'February - 02';
>   data['3'] = 'March - 03';   
>   data['4'] = 'April - 04';
>   data['5'] = 'May - 05';
>   data['6'] = 'June - 06';
>   data['7'] = 'July - 07';
>   data['8'] = 'August - 08';
>   data['9'] = 'September - 09';
>   data['10'] =  'October - 10';
>   data['11'] = 'November - 11';
>   data['12'] = 'December - 12';
>
>   for(var val in data) {
>   $('<option />', {value: ("0" + val).slice(-2),text: 
>    data[val]}).appendTo(D_field);
>    }
> ```

Thanks
I used array for storing data and also referred to the below solution :

[How to format numbers by prepending 0 to single-digit numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043026/how-to-format-numbers-by-prepending-0-to-single-digit-numbers/50757763)

I needed to send values in the form such as: 01 for (jan), (02) for feb ...and soon because I am creating a form for credit card details, which links to a payment gateway. So, I think prepending 0 to single digit number when sending data is the solution. Whereas, the value in the option could be 1(jan), 2(feb) for it to display in correct order.