# How to generate an array of Images using for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write an array of images, but I have a lot of images so I'm trying to use "for loop" to generate it.

my current code is :

```
var images = [
    "/images/image0000.png",
    "/images/image0005.png",
    "/images/image0010.png",
    "/images/image0015.png",
    "/images/image0020.png",
    "/images/image0025.png",
    "/images/image0030.png",
    "/images/image0040.png",
    "/images/image0045.png",
    "/images/image0050.png"
];
```

I have more images to add. so I would like to know how to use for loop to generate this.

The last image is `/images/image3360.png`

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "generate"? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Do these increment their "index" by 5 every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't want to generate the actual images, but rather fill an array with filenames. The simplest way would be:

```js
const MAX = 3360;
const PREFIX = "/images/image";
const EXT = ".png";
const arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= MAX; i += 5) {
  arr.push(
    PREFIX + ("0000" + i).slice(-4) + EXT
  );
}
```

The slice thing comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043026/how-to-format-numbers-by-prepending-0-to-single-digit-numbers).

Comment: And why exactly is that?

Comment: sorry, my fault. Didn't see that you were slicing the string. Reasonable solution indeed, assuming the "jump" criteria to 3360 is actually numeric.

Comment: Indeed, but given the brevity of this question one must make some assumptions.

Comment: I known, though I personally think there are **not** enough informations to properly answer to the question. In any case, you deserve a +1 for the brevity of your answer and for the clever usage of slice, definitely the most suitable solution for that scenario, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const step = 5; // Steps
const imgNumber = 3360/step; // Image number
const images = []; // Array to hold images


for(i = 0; i<=imgNumber; i++) {
   const currNum = i*step; // Calculate suffix
   let str = "/images/image0000";
   str = str.substring(0, str.length - currNum.toString().length); // Compile number
   images.push(`${str}${currNum}.png`); // Store the image in the array
}
console.log(images);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
let images = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= 3360; i += 5) {
    let imageString = "";
    let numberOfZeros = 4 - i.toString().length;

    for (let j = 0; j < numberOfZeros; j++) {
        imageString += "0";
    }
    images.push("/images/image" + imageString + i.toString() + ".png");
}
```

This essentially runs a for loop which increments by 5 each time, calculates the amount of leading zeros needed, then runs another for loop to add these leading zeros, and inserts a concatenation of this and the actual number inside the string which gets pushed to the array.