# What is the easiest way in Javascript to get just the sign of a number?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Number.sign() in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624920/number-sign-in-javascript)

Given some number variable, what is the easiest way to determine it's sign?

I keep ending up with code like this:

```
var direction = (vector[0] > 0) ? 1: (vector[0] < 0) ? -1: 0;
```

It seems less than elegant, when all I want is a -1 if the number is negative, 1 if positive and a 0 if it is 0.

By "easiest" I really mean elegant or less typing.

Alternatively, maybe there is a way to increase a value absolutely. Like if the number is negative, then subtract 1 from it, and if it is positive to add one to it. Math.abs() provides the absolute value, but there is no way to convert it back to a signed number once you run Math.abs().

Comment: With ES6 you can use `Math.sign()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign

However due to the implementation it has an unfortunate edge case: `Math.sign(-0) === Math.sign(+0)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
var sign = number && number / Math.abs(number);
```

Comment: I made a cosmetic edit to your post in order to rollback unjustified downvote.

Comment: This approach is pretty much always slower than the comparison-based one in benchmarks, division must be darn slow.

Answer (score 4):

How about defining a function to do it?

```
sign = function(n) { return n == 0 ? 0 : n/Math.abs(n); }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same as `return n || n/Math.abs(n)`?

Comment: You could even monkey-patch it into Math, and maybe call it `sgn` or `signum` to be more mathematicalish.

Comment: @elcanrs no, that's the opposite of what you want - it does the division only when n *is* zero.

Comment: @MarkReed: Meh, found a good duplicate.

Comment: @MarkReed: Right, what about `return n && n/Math.abs(n)`?

Comment: That would work, which is why two other people answered with that. :)

Comment: Oh, lol, didn't even notice.

Answer (score 2):

You can divide the number by its absolute and you'll get the sign:

```
var sign = number && number / Math.abs(number);
```

Comment: What about when number is 0?

Comment: @JamieWong you're right. Updated my code

Comment: Wow, and the && takes care of 0.  Great answers!

Answer (score 2):

If you want a shorter way, and you know it's a number, and you don't mind being limited to a signed 32 bit range, you can do this:

```
n ? -(n >>> 31) || 1 : 0;
```

---

- if `n` is `0`, then `0`
- if `n >>> 31` is `1`, it was signed, so negativ, and will be negated to `-1`
- if `n >>> 31` is `0`, it was not signed, so positive and will default to `1`

Comment: Note This assumes `n` is Int32, not Long and will fail for negative `n < -(2**31 + 1)`.

Comment: @PaulS.: Yep, noted the range limitation in my answer. :)

Comment: I didn't mark this as the correct one because it is not super intuitive for most people, but wow it is short. I really like this approach and thank you for posting it!

Comment: @BishopZ: Thanks. I just realized I had one more character than needed, so I updated it. You're right, it's not the most intuitive bit of code. I was mostly just curious to see what I could come up with. :-)

Comment: Note that this fails if -1 < x < 0. Conversion to int rounds to 0 and the sign is lost.