# Javascript multiline whitespace strip with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, whitespace, strip

I'm looking for effective way of multiline whitespace-stripping of text string

It should

1. Replace all `\r` with `\n`.
2. Remove any leading and trailing whitespaces in each line.
3. Remove empty and only-whitespace lines.
4. Replace all whitespace-sequencies in each line with a single space.
5. Respect all unicode whitespace characters.

So, for a given string

```
var string = ' \n\t \r  \r  \xA0\n <1>  \r     \n\r\r\n\n   <2> \t \t \r \t  \r \r <3>   \n  <a    a   a   a> \r \r \r \r\t  \n   \n  ';
```

It should return

```
"<1>\n<2>\n<3>\n<a a a a>"
```

So far I came up to this:

```
string
    .replace(/[ \f\t\v\u00a0\u1680\u180e\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000]+/g, ' ')
    .replace(/ ?[\n\r][\n\r ]*/g, '\n')
    .replace(/^\n|\n$/g, '')
;
```

Can you suggest a "better" way?

**Please, do not suggest `.split().map().join()`s**

Comment: I would use `split('\n')` to split it up by line, iterate over the lines, and then `join` them back to gether.

Comment: I would read the question to the end before answering...

Comment: gee, take a step back. @Barmar was giving you suggestions from his every-day experience, not an SO Answer!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that last line. But I don't understand why you're against that, it seems like an arbitrary restriction.

Comment: This regex approach is valid. It is working. What enhancement are you looking for?

Comment: Less code / more performant / less trivial... It is about the "art of coding". Doing trivial things in different manner. [Look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624920/number-sign-in-javascript).