# Hash distribution, why is 0 always heavily weighted?

Tags: javascript, hash, string-hashing

I wrote a quick canvas visualization to see the distribution of a hashing algorithm that I ported from C++ to JavaScript.

I'm seeing odd behavior in that no matter what I mod the hash by, 0 is heavily biased, in that it is selected exactly twice as often than most other numbers from the hashing function.

You can see the demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/x5L73/2/

and the original C++ algorithm: http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/hash.html

And the part of the code I'm referring to, which is at the bottom of the jsFiddle:

```
// hash is 0 twice as often as anything else
var hash = app.Hash( word ) % ( 3499 )
  ,   b1 = 0|hash / 59
  ,   b2 =   hash % 59;
```

What is odd to me is that `hash` is zero twice as often as it is *any* other value, regardless of what I choose to mod it by.  In this example, it is zero `1/3499` times, whereas *any* other number is hit `1/6998` times.  This was determined through brute force testing via:

```
if( hash!==1234 ){ nonZero++; }else{ zero++ } // 1234 is a random number to check       
if( Math.random() < .00001 ){ console.log( zero, nonZero, 0|nonZero/zero ); }
```

What am I missing here???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this is a very fun fact that might come in handy wwhen dealing with Integers, just like hashes, the error is **not** due to the fact that JavaScript *has* a negative zero too...

The original cause, as reported by OP was:

> It's because I was accidentally discarding all negative numbers in the visualization.

Yep, negative numbers are not that trivial, our minds tend to ignore them sometimes - especially when they are focusing on a specific, difficult problem involving integers for a long time, just like trying to figure out good hashing methods, then switching to a seemingly lot easier task: displaying the results...

**So the real answer is:** besides a negative zero, JavaScript has quite some more negative numbers too... Don't forget to take them into count - even in the *easy* task of visualization.

TL;DR

I leave this here, as this *might* come in handy for anyone having similar issues in the future, as it *might* cause a similar scenario.

Look at this question: [+0 and -0 in JavaScript (negative zero and positive zero in JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223359/0-and-0-in-javascript-negative-zero-and-positive-zero-in-javascript)

Quote:

> JavaScript uses [IEEE 745 standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223359/0-and-0-in-javascript-negative-zero-and-positive-zero-in-javascript) to represent numbers. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_zero):
>
> > **Signed zero** is zero with an associated sign. In ordinary arithmetic, −0 = +0 = 0. However, in computing, some number representations allow for the existence of two zeros, often denoted by **−0 (negative zero)** and **+0 (positive zero)**. This occurs in some signed number representations for integers, and in most floating point number representations. The number 0 is usually encoded as +0, but can be represented by either +0 or −0.
> >
> > The IEEE 754 standard for floating point arithmetic (presently used by most computers and programming languages that support floating point numbers) requires both +0 and −0. The zeroes can be considered as a variant of the extended real number line such that 1/−0 = −∞ and 1/+0 = +∞, division by zero is only undefined for ±0/±0 and ±∞/±∞.

Comment: I never knew that. Wish I could +1 this some more!

Comment: Actually, it's not.  It's because I was accidentally discarding all negative numbers in the visualization :)

But you led me to the answer, so I'll accept this if you edit it (I don't want to accept it now because as useful as it is it might mis-lead other people)

Comment: @cwolves I had quite some similar AHA moments myself :) I edited the answer, but left the reference to the -0, as I still think it _might_ cause similar effects.