# JavaScript number approximation

Tags: javascript

I used function :

```
fixedTo(1)
```

to approximate a number like this:

```
-3.43321e-11
```

but the problem is that the result of approximation is:

```
-0.0
```

with minus sign.

This is a problem because in math doesn't exist 0 with minus sign and if I do:

```
if(-0.0 === 0.0){}
```

it returns me false insted of true. How can I resolve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are +0 and -0 the same?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223359/are-0-and-0-the-same)

Comment: please post your entire code, i mean the approximation method

Comment: The problem is that comparison is inside an iteraction and I need sign of number except for zero @FrédéricHamidi

Comment: If you Google JavaScript negative zero you'll find lots of posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a common problem when comparing float values. Float values are almost never exactly like you write them. So your -0.0 is in reality more like -0.000001 or something.

If you want to compare float values, you have to deal with a certain amount of error, like this:

```
if(Math.abs(value1 - value2) < 0.001) {
```

So you basically treat all floats whose difference is smaller than 0.001 as equal.