# What do "positive" and "negative" mean in ECMAScript? +0 and -0

Tags: javascript, language-lawyer, specifications

I was reading the [ECMAScript 5.1 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.10). It says:

> The `slice` method takes two arguments, *start* and *end* [...]. If *start* is negative, it is treated as
>   *length+start* where *length* is the length of the array. If *end* is negative, it is treated as *length+end* where length is the *length*
>   of the array.

What does "negative" mean? It makes sense that, like in math,

- If `num > 0`, then `num` it is positive
- If `num < 0`, then `num` is negative.

But what about `+0` and `-0`? In math there is a single `0`, which is not positive nor negative. My guess was that, in ECMAScript,

- `+0` (a.k.a. positive zero) is positive.
- `-0` (a.k.a. negative zero) is negative.

But I tried using `-0` with `slice`, and browsers treat it as non-negative.

Then, are both `+0` and `-0` non-positive and non-negative, despite their names?

Where is the positiveness or negativeness of a number defined? I didn't find that defined in the ECMAScript spec. Is the definition inherited from IEEE 754?

Comment: Interestingly, `Math.abs(-0) === -0` is true (in Chrome).

Comment: @ssube So is `0 === -0`.

Comment: @ssube Yes, `0 === -0`. [The Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6) doesn't differentiate them. [The SameValue Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.12) does. In ECMAScript 6, `Object.is(0, -0)` is `false`.

Comment: Related: [Are +0 and -0 the same?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223359/are-0-and-0-the-same)

Comment: An interesting question. I suppose `negative` is treated as `'less than zero'` in this case. But for `-0 * 0` (and similar arithmetic ops), it's clear that the sign does matter. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terms "positive number" and "negative number" are indeed defined in the ECMAScript spec:

> [**8.5 The Number Type**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5)
>
> The Number type has exactly 18437736874454810627 (that is,
>   2<sup>64</sup>−2<sup>53</sup>+3) values [...]
>
> The 9007199254740990 (that is, 2<sup>53</sup>−2) distinct
>   “Not-a-Number” values of the IEEE Standard are represented in
>   ECMAScript as a single special *NaN* value [...]
>
> There are two other special values, called *positive Infinity* and
>   *negative Infinity* [...]
>
> The other 18437736874454810624 (that is,
>   2<sup>64</sup>−2<sup>53</sup>) values are called the finite numbers.
>   Half of these are **positive numbers** and half are **negative
>   numbers**; for every finite positive Number value there is a
>   corresponding negative value having the same magnitude.

Therefore,

- Since `+0` and `-0` are two of those finite numbers, each must either be positive or negative.
- Since each finite positive number must have a negative counterpart, either `+0` is positive and `-0` is negative, or the opposite.
- It would be too trollish if the positive zero was a negative number, and negative zero was a positive one. So we can (probably) assume that `+0` is positive and `-0` is negative.

However, according to the following, neither `+0` nor `-0` can be negative:

> [**5.2 Algorithm Conventions**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5)
>
> The mathematical function *abs(x)* yields the absolute value of *x*,
>   which is *−x* if *x* is **negative (less than zero)** and otherwise is
>   *x* itself.

In fact, in most cases the spec seems to differentiate the case when a variable is positive or negative from the case when it's zero. For example,

> [**5.2 Algorithm Conventions**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5)
>
> The mathematical function *sign(x)* yields 1 if *x* is **positive**
>   and −1 if
>   *x* is **negative**. The sign function is not used in this standard for cases when *x* is **zero**.

## Therefore, the spec is contradictory.

Comment: For `slice` (and all other sequence methods), the meaning of *less than zero* is used though.

Comment: How did you conclude that your second quote implies that "neither `+0` nor `-0` can be negative"? The quote mentions nothing about `+0` or `-0`. There is no contradiction here.

Comment: `-0` can represent numbers less than 0, (eg. `-1^1000000000`). In such a case, abs yields `+0`, which is perfectly consistent with what is described in the quote and everything else in the spec.

Comment: @Asad The second quote says that negative numbers are less than zero. And both `+0` or `- 0` correspond to the math value zero, which is not less than zero. So they can't be negative. Are you saying that implementations can know if a `-0` in memory comes from a literal `-0` or a negative number very close to zero? Wouldn't that additional information need to be stored somewhere, and then require more than 64 bits?

Comment: @Oriol Implementations **can't** know whether the `-0` in memory comes from a literal `-0` or from some really small number. So the `-0` in memory could represent a really small negative number, just as it could represent 0.

Comment: Here's an example: The correct value for the abs function, when operating on a representation of a negative real number, is the representation of the corresponding positive real number. An example of this is the number -1e-10000 ∈R, which is represented in memory by `-0`. Using the abs function should return the representation of 1e-10000 ∈R, which is `+0`. This is exactly what happens.

Answer (score 3):

Your confusion is in this part:

> But what about `+0` and `-0`? In math there is a single `0`, which is not positive nor negative. My guess was that, in ECMAScript,
>
> - `+0` (a.k.a. positive zero) is positive.
> - `-0` (a.k.a. negative zero) is negative.

`+0` is not positive; `-0` is not negative.  Conceptually they both represent the number zero *or, when underflow occurs, any number with a magnitude too small to be represented with the finite number of bits available*.

The decision to have `+0` and `-0` comes more from IEEE than from ECMA.

Comment: "`+0` is not positive; `-0` is not negative". Great, but do you have any source?

Answer (score 2):

Things can be confusing if you don't distinguish between the *literals* `+0` and `-0`, which represent the mathematical value 0, and the *values* `+0` and `-0`, which are the in memory representation, respectively, for:

1. Any mathematical value from 0 to the smallest positive real number that can be stored in the double precision 64-bit data format
2. Any mathematical value from the largest negative real number that can be stored in the double precision 64-bit data format to 0

If you have a variable containing the `Number` instance `-0`, this could be representing the real number 0 (which obviously has no sign), or it could be representing the real number 10^-10000.

If you see the *literal* `-0` or `+0` in code, this will be interpreted as the real number 0, which is stored (just like any sufficiently tiny but not actually 0 real number) as the `Number` `-0` or `+0`, as the case may be.

Here are some relevant sections from the spec that will hopefully clarify things:

1. [Numeric literals](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.3)
2. [The `Number` type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5)
3. [Algorithm conventions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-5.2)
4. [Why `-0===+0`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6)

Comment: Then, is the positiveness or negativeness of an ECMAScript number defined as the positiveness or negativeness of its mathematical value? So, since the value of both `+0` and `-0` is 0, they are not positive nor negative?

Comment: @Oriol: Right below the cited section there is used the annotation "*… if x is negative (less than zero) …*". I would indeed conclude that `-0` and `+0` are neither negative nor positive, if they were concerned the spec used the explicit term "nonnegative" instead of "positive".

Comment: @Oriol I've expanded my answer. Hopefully that will help explain things a bit better.

Comment: Not sure if the difference between a literal and the memory representation matters. The literal `0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001` behaves exactly as `+0`, because they are both stored as `+0`.

Comment: @Oriol The difference between a literal and the memory representation matters precisely because the that tiny literal is actually stored in memory as `+0`. That `+0` in memory represents the real number 10^-x, where x is however many decimal places there are there. If on the other hand you literally typed `+0` or `-0`, both of those represent a different real number, 0, yet are also stored in memory as `+0` or `-0`, respectively. At this point it isn't entirely clear what your question is: maybe it would be easier to explain if you restated what you're asking in more formal terms than +veness.