# Negative zero in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, negative-number, unary-operator

I've just noticed that I can do the following in JavaScript:

```
var z = -0;
console.log(z); // prints -0
```

Why does the unary negation works on zero?

Is this one of the many JavaScript quirks or it does (somehow) have a purpose?

---

P.S.:

It seems to be happening on Firefox 38.0a2 and Chrome 41.0.2272. On Node.js v0.10.36 doesn't happen. Dunno about IE.

Comment: Checkout this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223359/are-0-and-0-the-same

Comment: It works in io.js (1.6.1).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've just encountered the [signed zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero).

> The IEEE 754 standard for floating-point arithmetic (presently used by most computers and programming languages that support floating point numbers) requires both +0 and −0. Real arithmetic with signed zeros can be considered a variant of the extended real number line such that 1/−0 = −∞ and 1/+0 = +∞; division is only undefined for ±0/±0 and ±∞/±∞.

All numbers in Javascript are floating-point, so zeros must be signed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a problem. At least `alert(-0 == 0)` returns `true`. I guess if there is one bit used for the sign this bit can also be set if the value is `0`. Hovever, it remains the same number.