# javascript equation resulting in -0

Tags: javascript, math

I have the javascript equation:

```
var sbal=pfWeight-gWeight-adjm;
$("#result").html(sbal.toFixed(5));
```

If the result is 0, I assign the result the CSS color green.
If it is not 0, I assign the result the CSS color red.

My problem is that sometimes the math comes out as -0 and thus displays as red.

I even tried

```
if(sbal===0){sbal=parseInt(0);}
```

sbal===0 returns true.

How can I work around this?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jd40b8av/)

I know that [Are +0 and -0 the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223359/are-0-and-0-the-same) addresses WHY -0 = +0 but it does not supply and answer on how to fix the problem.

Comment: use Mat.abs() to get a positive value

Comment: -0 should be equal to +0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223359/are-0-and-0-the-same could you show us the code where you attribute the CSS color?

Comment: please see jsfiddle link for css code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your only issue is that it sometimes returns -0, you can simply calculate the absolute value of your return value

```
Math.abs(-0); // 0
```

Edit:
Javascript has a strange rounding of floating point numbers: If you roundup the result it works fine, then you don't need Math.abs(-0). As was pointed out -0 and 0 should be the same value.

This worked for me:

```
var sbal = Math.ceil(pfWeight - gWeight - adjm);
```

Comment: I get the same. I added a jsfiddle link. thanks

Comment: I updated the answer, Javascript floating point number rounding seems a bit strange.