# JavaScript - Detecting the difference between positive zero and negative zero

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) to calculate the difference between two times. The weird thing is about this library is the difference between today and today is 0. The difference between today and tomorrow is -0.

My question is, how do I differentiate between 0 and -0. It seems JavaScript treats them the same.

So for example if I write the following code:

```
if (tomorrow === -0)
    console.log('It is tomorrow!');
else if (tomorrow === 0)
    console.log('It is today!');
```

Here's an example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cs1jxwmt/1/) as to how it handles the returned values (I am in Australia so depending on where you are in the word you may have to adjust the today and tomorrow dates)

Comment: For me, `tomorrow` is showing up as `-1`, not `-0`. (via your fiddle)

Comment: about 0 and -0 problem, can you take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223359/are-0-and-0-the-same

Comment: Where are you, like physically on Planet Earth right now?

Comment: When I try it here in my continent, with `23` and `24` I get your result. However, the difference in days is really zero for both of those, since it's currently the 23rd (so zero days) and it's less than half a day until it's the 24th) which rounds to zero days too. In JavaScript, `0` is `===` to `-0`.

Comment: Shouldn't the difference between today and tomorrow be 1?

Comment: @RobG I agree. I've opend an issue on their [GitHub](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2503)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`1/val > 0` will do what you want. Returns `true` for positive and `false` for negative.

This works because `1/-0` returns negative infinity, and `1/0` returns positive infinity, which are then comparable. You could also do something like `1/val == Infinity`.

Comment: As of ES2015, you can also check for equality with Object.is(). It also checks special cases (e.g. Object.is(-0, -0) is true while Object.is(0, -0) is false)

Answer (score 11):

As pointed out in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223359/are-0-and-0-the-same) (and in the comments), in JavaScript `+0 === -0` indeed evaluates to `true` by design.

You can use `Infinity`/`-Infinity` to see a difference (technically, `+0`/`-0` might not be the only numbers to produce infinite values, so I left the additional check in):

```
var positiveZero = +0;
var negativeZero = -0;

console.log(positiveZero === 0 && 1/positiveZero === Infinity); // true
console.log(positiveZero === 0 && 1/positiveZero === -Infinity); // false

console.log(negativeZero === 0 && 1/negativeZero === Infinity); // false
console.log(negativeZero === 0 && 1/negativeZero === -Infinity); // true
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1f69t7w5/1/)

See also [this blog post](http://www.wirfs-brock.com/allen/posts/128) for more details and yet another solution with ECMAScript 5:

```
function isNegative0(x) {
   if (x!==0) return false;
   var obj=Object.freeze({z:-0});
   try {
      Object.defineProperty(obj,'z',{value:x});
   } catch (e) {return false};
   return true;
}
```