# -0 in JavaScript after using Math.round? What is -0?

Tags: javascript

I just wanted to generate random integer number in range `<-1,1>`, that is -1, 0 or 1. I think this code nails it:

```
Math.round(Math.random()*2-1)
```

But I'm getting one more value apart from -1, 0 and 1. I'm not sure what is that supposed to be:

[image: image description]

Now I don't think this is implementation error, but if it is, I'm using Firefox 41 and same thing happened in Google Chrome 39. When I tried to log `-0` in console it appeared as `-0` but `-0` converted to `String` appears as `"0"`. What is it? Can I use it for something, like some cool programming hacks and workarounds? Can it cause some errors if I don't just ignore it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

Comment: Related [Are +0 and -0 the same?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7223359/218196)

Comment: An important thing to note is that `-0 === 0` returns true, so it's not something you have to worry about. If you want to transform -0 into 0, just write `myvar = myvar || 0;` or do any operation on it. `(-0).toString()` returns `"0"` too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Two Zeros**

Because JavaScript’s numbers keep magnitude and sign separate, each nonnegative number has a negative, including 0.
The rationale for this is that whenever you represent a number digitally, it can become so small that it is indistinguishable from 0, because the encoding is not precise enough to represent the difference. Then a signed zero allows you to record “from which direction” you approached zero; that is, what sign the number had before it was considered zero.

from [here](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch11.html)

---

More technical stuff if you are interested.

The implementation of -0 and +0 is introduced in 1985 by IEEE as part of the [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).  The standard addressed [many problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#IEEE_754_design_rationale) found in the diverse floating point implementations that made them difficult to use reliably and portably.

**The standard defines**

- arithmetic formats: sets of binary and decimal floating-point data, which consist of finite numbers (including signed zeros and subnormal numbers), infinities, and special "not a number" values (NaNs)
- interchange formats: encodings (bit strings) that may be used to exchange floating-point data in an efficient and compact form
- rounding rules: properties to be satisfied when rounding numbers during arithmetic and conversions
- operations: arithmetic and other operations on arithmetic formats
  exception handling: indications of exceptional conditions (such as division by zero, overflow, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

ECMAScript has two zero numbers: `+0` and `-0`.

They are considered equal by most comparison algorithms:

```
+0 == -0          // true (Equality comparison)
+0 === -0         // true (StrictEquality comparison)
[+0].includes(-0) // true (SameValueZero comparison)
```

However, they are different number values:

```
Object.is(+0, -0) // false (SameValue comparison)
```

Usually, both zeros behave identically in mathematical calculations. However,

```
1 / +0 === +Infinity
1 / -0 === -Infinity
```

In this case, you get `-0` because [`Math.round`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.15) is defined as follows:

> If *x* is less than 0 but greater than or equal to -0.5, the result is
>   −0.

In general, if you have an integer between −2<sup>31</sup> and 2<sup>31</sup>−1, and you want to convert it to `+0` if it's `-0`, and don't alter it otherwise, you can use bitwise OR:

```
-1 | 0 // -1
-0 | 0 // +0
+0 | 0 // +0
+1 | 0 // +1
```

However, in your case you could just take the `-1` outside of `Math.round`:

```
Math.round(Math.random()*2) - 1
```

But note using `Math.round` will produce a non-uniform probability distribution. Consider using

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*3) - 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `Math.round` works as specified in [the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.15):

> If x is less than 0 but greater than or equal to -0.5, the result is −0.

`Math.random` returns number between 0 (zero) and 1 (one) exclusively, so you will have several occurances of that rule.