# What is the purpose of having both positive and negative zero (+0, also written as 0, and -0)?

Tags: javascript, numbers

According to the ECMAScript 6.0 specification:

> ...there is both a positive zero and a negative zero. For brevity, these values are also referred to for expository purposes by the symbols +0 and -0, respectively. (Note that these two different zero Number values are produced by the program expressions +0 (or simply 0) and -0.)

So, +0 and -0 are different Number values but they are considered equal.
I've checked that `-0 === +0` equates to `true`.

I assume this is just an artifact of how numbers are stored in memory and that there is no benefit/purpose/use of these values.

Am I correct?

Also, wikipedia states:

> while the two zero representations behave as equal under numeric
>   comparisons, they yield different results in some operations

Are there any such operations in JavaScript?

Comment: Perhaps [*wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of how numbers are stored and represented in the memory, and processed, specially for floating point arithmetic.

> Signed zero is zero with an associated sign. In ordinary arithmetic, −0 = +0 = 0. However, in computing, some number representations allow for the existence of two zeros, often denoted by −0 (negative zero) and +0 (positive zero). This occurs in some signed number representations for integers, and in most floating point number representations. The number 0 is usually encoded as +0, but can be represented by either +0 or −0.

More in this previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223359/are-0-and-0-the-same)