# Why am i getting -0 instead of 0?

Tags: c

I have written a code in c which gives me rotation of point by angle given in the form of triples.
When I compile and run for test case it gives me output as -0,7 .
Where as the same code in python gives me output as 0,7 . 
When I run the same code on online compiling platforms it gives me correct output.
I am using codeblocks windows 10 os.
Is there something wrong with codeblocks?
What should i do?

C code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    double xp,yp,xq,yq,a,b,c;
    double t,xn,yn;
    int z;
    scanf("%d",&z);
  //  printf("Enter coordinates of p \n");
    scanf("%lf%lf",&xp,&yp);
   // printf("\nEnter triple \n");
    scanf("%lf%lf%lf",&a,&b,&c);
   // printf("\nEnter coordinates of q \n");
    scanf("%lf%lf",&xq,&yq);
    t=asin(b/c);
    if(z==0)
    {
    xn=xp*cos(t)-yp*sin(t)-xq*cos(t)+yq*sin(t)+xq;
    yn=xp*sin(t)+yp*cos(t)-xq*sin(t)-yq*cos(t)+yq;
    }
    else
    {
    xn=xp*cos(t)+yp*sin(t)-xq*cos(t)-yq*sin(t)+xq;
    yn=-xp*sin(t)+yp*cos(t)+xq*sin(t)-yq*cos(t)+yq;
    }
    printf("%lf     %lf",xn,yn);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
4 7
3 4 5
2 3
-0.000000     7.000000
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 10.675 s
Press any key to continue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088742/what-is-the-purpose-of-having-both-positive-and-negative-zero-0-also-written
```

Comment: Maybe you have "-0" because your printf do not print the decimal part and your real number is "-0.7". So, appart from having something like "if (-1 < xn && xn <= 0) { xn = 0;}", i don't see how your printf can be correct.

Comment: That is not the case. I have edited the problem that contains the full values of xn and yn.

Comment: I have tested your main, I got "0.000000".

Comment: I am using codeblocks so is it due to someting wrong in codeblocks?I can upload snapshot if you want.

Comment: I don't see how C::B can be the culprit ... It's more likely OS dependant. But the trick with "xn == 0.0 ? 0.0 : xn" work, so you could use that.

Comment: @AniketBote you got a sensible answer, anything wrong with it? :o

Comment: I m trying to understand it.I am new in c programming.

Comment: I used online compiler it gave me correct output.So what is going wrong exactly?

Comment: Change `printf("%lf     %lf",xn,yn);` into `printf("%.80lf     %lf",xn,yn);` What does it print now?

Comment: Its giving me very small negative number.@Eric postpischil is right.

Comment: How should i round that to 0.

Comment: `How should i round that to 0.` See the answer from tmlen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50099047/4386427

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For floating point values there are two zeroes `0.0` and `-0.0`. They compare as equal (e.g. `-0.0 == 0.0` returns `1`) but they are two distinct values. They are there for symmetry, because for any small value other than 0, the sign does make a mathematical difference. For some edge cases they make a difference. For example `1.0/0.0 == INFINITY` and `1.0/-0.0 == -INFINITY`. (`INFINITY`, `-INFINITY` and `NAN`) are also values that the floating point variables can take.

To make `printf` not print `-0` for `-0.0` and any small that would be truncated to `0` or `-0`, one way is to artificially put very small values to `0.0`, for example:

```
if(abs(x) < 1e-5) x = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 3):

The most likely thing here is that you don't actually have a signed `-0.0`, but your *formatting* is presenting it to you that way.

You'll get a signed negative zero in floating point if one of your calculations yields a negative subnormal number that's rounded to zero.

If you do indeed have a pure signed zero, then one workaround is to clobber it with a the ternary conditional operator as `printf` does reserve the right to propagate the signed zero into the output: `f == 0.0 ? 0.0 : f` is one such scheme or even with the flashier but obfuscated `f ? f : 0.0`. The C standard *defines* `-0.0` to be equal to `0.0`. Another way (acknowledge @EricPostpischil) is to add `0.0` to the value.

Comment: It does print a sign for `-0.0` (for example with `printf("%f", -0.0);`)

Comment: `printf("%lf     %lf",xn ? xn : 0.0,yn ? yn : 0.0);`

Comment: I dont think I have actual signed 0 but my formatting is presenting me that way as your solution in comment didnt work. What should i do now.

Comment: I used online compiler it gave me correct output for the same code.So what exactly is wrong?

Comment: There is no need to use the ternary operator to change -0 to +0. Simply add 0. (One floating-point instruction instead of test, branch, and move/load.) But I suspect that is not the actual problem. More likely the result is a small negative value.

Comment: Actually I am getting correct output when I am using online compiling platforms.But when i am compiling in my pc its giving me negative 0.