# How to negate all elements in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the shortest way to negate all elements in a javascript array, with reasonable efficiency?

For example, the solution would convert `[0, 18, -1, -2, 1, 3]` to `[0, -18, 1, 2, -1, -3]`

The solution does not need to handle any values that are NaN/undefined/null, because the array I need this for does not contain any of those values.

Here is what I normally do (with array `array`):

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i]*=-1
}
```

The problem is that I need to invert this array in several places, so don't want to reuse large code.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try? Shouldn't have been difficult to at least make an attempt and show that attempt rather than ask how to do it from scratch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be `array.map` returning the negative of each value. Adding in arrow function for an even shorter syntax.

```
var negatedArray = array.map(value => -value);
```

Comment: Nice approach though it gives `-0`.

Comment: Is -0 any different than 0?

Comment: isn't this even simpler `array.map(value => -value);` since, as @AaronJanse points out, he doesn't need to handle nulls or undefineds

Comment: @choz `-0` is different than `+0`. Otherwise, `1/+0` and `1/-0` would also be the same.

Comment: @Oriol Both result in Infinity, even though their binary representation are not same.

Comment: @choz No, `1/+0` is `+Infinity`, and `1/-0` is `-Infinity`. And clearly `+Infinity !== -Infinity`, e.g. `-Infinity < +Infinity`. You can also test `Object.is(+0, -0)`, which produces `false` (they are different).

Comment: @Oriol Let's not go to deep.. `+0 === -0` alright.. This [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223359/are-0-and-0-the-same) might help.

Comment: There are some features that are bad just because they aren't obvious and cause "bugs" due to user error. One of which is the difference between +0 and -0

Comment: From now on, I will use this for tons of things, not just negating.

Comment: I have used it like this: `var negatedArray = myArray.map(value => value !== 0 ? -value: value );` To avoid confusion of +/- 0

Answer (score 1):

> negate all elements in a javascript array

I think you are referring to negate only the positive number.

```
var _myArray = [0, 18, -1, -2, 1, 3]
var _invArray = [];
_myArray.forEach(function(item){
  item >0 ?(_invArray.push(item*(-1))) :(_invArray.push(item))
})
console.log(_invArray);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/xpa45gyt/)

Comment: No, but good solution. `_invArray.push(-Math.abs(item))` could have worked too, if that was what I was looking for