# Any examples / scenarios where negative zero in JavaScript make a big difference?

Tags: javascript, negative-zero

I know that JavaScript has both a normal zero 0 (known as a positive zero +0) and a negative zero -0, however I have never come across a situation where I had to use -0.

There are some existing posts on stack overflow about how positive and negative zeros are similar/different, but none of them explain real life use-cases/examples of it.

Comment: Why is this queation relevant??

Comment: In my opinion it is more mathematical representation.  + and - are signs that basically helpful to add some directionality sense to the value. For instance, if you are calculating `2/0 = Infinity` , `2/-0 = - infinity` . So, now infinity has a context  in your study or algorithm or some calculations. The `- infinity` represents the value to be very low. While `infinity` represents the value to be very high.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223359/are-0-and-0-the-same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume we're studying the function `y = 1/x` and we'd like to know how it behaves when x is small. Let's take `x=1, x=0.1, x=0.01` and calculate the func:

```js
x = 1;
while(x) {
    x /= 10;
    document.write(x + ' ' + 1/x + '<br>');
}
```

As you can see, it approaches towards positive infinity. `1/x` is equal to `Infinity` because at some point `x` gets so small that it's indistinguishable from `0`, and `1/0 = Infinity`. Note that this is the "positive" Infinity, that is, "a very big number".

Now, let's start with `-1` instead of `x=1`:

```js
x = -1;
while(x) {
    x /= 10;
    document.write(x + ' ' + 1/x + '<br>');
}
```

The answer is now `-Infinity`, that is, the function approaches towards the negative Infinity, "a very small number". Of course, this is also correct, but how did the computer get that? We just learned that `1/0 = (positive) Infinity`? The secret is that the zero in the last snippet is actually negative, so `x` on the last iteration is `-0` and not just `0`, and `1/-0` gives `-Infinity`. Without the signed zero, the last snippet would give an incorrect result.

Hope that explains it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

There are scientific reasons for including the sign, which you can read in more depth here on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero#Scientific_uses).

*From the Wikipedia article on Signed Zero:*

Informally, one may use the notation "−0" for a negative value that was rounded to zero. This notation may be useful when a negative sign is significant; for example, when tabulating Celsius temperatures, where a negative sign means below freezing.

In statistical mechanics, one sometimes uses negative temperatures to describe systems with population inversion, which can be considered to have a temperature greater than positive infinity, because the coefficient of energy in the population distribution function is −1/Temperature. In this context, a temperature of −0 is a (theoretical) temperature larger than any other negative temperature, corresponding to the (theoretical) maximum conceivable extent of population inversion, the opposite extreme to +0.[5]"