# Jasmine does not evaluate 0 toEqual -0

Tags: typescript, jasmine

I have a test in Typescript that is comparing two objects, and the results show are:

```
Chrome 57.0.2987 (Mac OS X 10.12.4) Hex should round 1 FAILED
    Expected Hex({ q: 0, r: 0, s: -0 }) to equal Hex({ q: 0, r: -0, s: 0 }).
```

**How can a value of -0 not equal 0 in Jasmine?**  The only thing I can think of is that it is converting to a string.

```
  it ('should verify 0 === -0', () => {
    expect(0).toEqual(-0);
  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are +0 and -0 the same?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223359/are-0-and-0-the-same)

Comment: That answer states `However, +0 === -0 evaluates to true. Why is that (...) ?`