# How to avoid negative 0 or -0 values in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsx, zero

I have tried using `toString()` and the bitwise operator `|` but I would like to use the precision and string output. As [@trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot) mentioned, it is caused by the precision value for e.g. -0.45 will result in -0.  I have the code here.

```
typeof predictedHours //number e.g. -0.45
precision = 0
value={predictedHours.toFixed(precision)}
typeof value //string e.g. "-0"
```

Question - Is there a one liner to convert -0 to 0 in this line - `value={predictedHours.toFixed(precision)}`?

Comment: Lots of relevant comments in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223359/are-0-and-0-the-same

Comment: Possibly question is triggered by `-0.001.toFixed(2) === "-0"`?

Comment: @trincot You got it correct. it is triggerred exactly because of that and I have a JSX element to throw the value in.

Comment: So what you want the string to be in that case? Just "0" instead of "-0"?

Comment: @trincot Correct!

Comment: Downvoters, I am sorry for bad language. Maybe I deserve the downvotes.

Comment: You could do `-0.001.toFixed(2).replace(/^-0$/, "0")`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I’m not aware of a particularly clean way to do it, but there’s always:

```
predictedHours.toFixed(0).replace('-0', '0')
```

Or, in general:

```
predictedHours.toFixed(precision).replace(/^-([.0]*)$/, '$1')
```

Comment: Simply add + 0 to the number.

Comment: @PrestonSoftware: There’s no reason to do that for this question. If you’re going to parse the string back to a number anyway, `(-0).toFixed(…)` already omits the sign.

Answer (score 8):

`num + 0`  is the most performant and fastest way.  `-0+0` is positive zero.  `0+0` is positive zero.  negative numbers stay negative, positive numbers stay positive.  this just drops the negative zero business if it is not useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do `value = +predictedHours.toFixed(precision) || 0` because `-0 || 0` is `0`

Comment: `-0 || 0` won't work here, because of `toFixed` returning a string and `"-0" !== 0`.

Comment: You're right, fixed my answer. Added a `+` to turn it into a number :)

Answer (score 0):

I think @trincot's suggestion is better so as to avoid any decimals like `-0.48.toFixed(2)` to be converted to positive. Took me a while to understand the regex. Just a little caveat though: Due to operator precedence negative numbers stay negative with toFixed when enclosed in brackets. Some examples here:

```
-0.001.toFixed(2).replace(/^-0$/, "0")
//0 '0'

console.log((-0.48).toFixed(0).replace(/^-0$/, '0')); Correct
//-0 '0'

console.log((-0.48).toFixed(2).replace(/^-0$/, '0')); Correct
//-0.48 '-0.48'

console.log(-0.48.toFixed(0).replace(/^-0$/, '0'));
//0 '0'

console.log(-0.48.toFixed(2).replace(/^-0$/, '0'));
//-0.48 '-0.48'
```

Also have a look at the examples here - [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by real decimals, but try with `(-0.0048).toFixed(2)`.

Comment: Yeah good point. Is there a way to avoid that by adding any optional characters in regex?

Comment: `console.log((-0.0048).toFixed(2).replace(/^-0.?0?/, '0'));` would return 00

Answer (score 0):

use `Math.abs()` to replace a -0 with an absolute number i.e. 0.