# +0 and -0 shows different behavior for int and float data

Tags: java, java-8

I have read this post [negative and positive zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223359/are-0-and-0-the-same).

To my understanding following code should give `true`  and `true`  as a output.

However, it is giving `false` and `true` as a output.

I'm comparing negative zero with a positive zero.

```
public class Test {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            float f = 0;
            float f2 = -f;
            Float F = new Float(f);
            Float F1 = new Float(f2);
            System.out.println(F1.equals(F));

            int i = 0;
            int i2 = -i;
            Integer I = new Integer(i);
            Integer I1 = new Integer(i2);
            System.out.println(I1.equals(I));
      }
  }
```

Why do we have different behavior for 0's for `Integer` and `Float` ?

Comment: If you check the javadocs, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#equals-java.lang.Object- The definition allows for hash tables to function properly. Also, there is no -0 integer.

Comment: @matt if -0 is not integer then it should be evaluated as false...

Comment: When you say i2 = -i; i2 takes the exact bit representation of i, there is no way to discern them. `i` and `i2` are exactly the same. Then when you create new `Integer`s they both wrap the exact same value. `I1.equals(I)` will be true.

Comment: Try `int i = Integer.MIN_VALUE, i2 = -i;`…

Comment: There is, by the way, no reason to use `new` for the wrapper types here. Just use, e.g. `Integer i = 0, i2 = -i;  System.out.println(i.equals(i2));  Float f1 = 0f, f2 = -f1; 
 System.out.println(f1.equals(f2));`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ints and floats are pretty different beasts in Java. Ints are encoded as [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), which has a single 0 value. Floats use [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) (the [32-bit variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) for floats, and [64-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) for doubles). IEEE 754 is somewhat complex, but for purpose of this answer, you just need to know that it has three sections, the first of which is a sign bit. That means for any float, there's a positive and negative variant¹. That includes 0, so floats actually have two "zero" values, +0 and -0.

As an aside, the two's complement that ints use is not the only way to encode integers in computer science. There are other methods, like [ones' complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement), but they have quirks — like having both a +0 and -0 as distinct values. ;-)

When you compare float primitives (and doubles), Java treats +0 and -0 as equal. But when you box them, Java treats them separately, as described in [`Float#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#equals-java.lang.Object-). This lets the equals method be consistent with their [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#hashCode--) implementation (as well as `compareTo`), which just uses the bits of the float (including that signed value) and shoves them as-is into an int.

They could have picked some other option for equals/hashCode/compareTo, but they didn't. I'm not sure what the design considerations there were. But in at least one regard, `Float#equals` was always going to diverge from the float primitive's `==`: In primitives, `NaN != NaN`, but [for all objects, `o.equals(o)` must also be true](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-). That means that if you had `Float f = Float.NaN`, then `f.equals(f)` even though `f.floatValue() != f.floatValue()`.

---

¹ NaN (not-a-number) values have a sign bit, but it doesn't have any meaning other than for ordering, and Java ignores it (even for ordering).

Answer (score 9):

This is one of [Float equals exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

> there are two exceptions:
>
> **If f1 represents +0.0f while f2 represents -0.0f**, or vice versa, the equal test has the value **false**

The why is described also:

> This definition allows hash tables to operate properly.

-0 and 0 will represented differently using Float's bit 31:

> Bit 31 (the bit that is selected by the mask 0x80000000) represents the sign of the floating-point number.

This isn't the case in `Integer`

Comment: question is why ? Is this hard and fast rule that we have to cram :(

Comment: @Joker Added the quote *allows hash tables to operate properly*

Comment: A key piece that this answer (and the javadoc) don't mention is that the difference is that in floats, +0 and -0 are different values -- equivalent, but different. Basically, floats have three parts to them, and the first part is a single bit that says whether the float is positive or negative. That's _not_ the case for ints (as represented in Java), which only have a single 0 value.

Comment: @yshavit Thanks, could you please share the same as an answer

Comment: @Joker *Bit 31 (the bit that is selected by the mask 0x80000000) represents the sign of the floating-point number.*

Answer (score 4):

For the integers, there is no distinction between -0 and 0 for integers because it uses [Twos compliment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation. So your integer example `i` and `i1` are exactly the same.

For the floats, there is a -0 representation, and it's value is equivalent to 0, but the bit representation is different. Hence new Float(0f) and new Float(-0f) would have different representations.

You can see the difference in the bit representations.

```
System.out.println(Float.floatToIntBits(-0f) + ", " + Float.floatToIntBits(0f));
```

> -2147483648, 0

And if you leave off the `f` to declare the `-0f` then it will be treated as an integer, and you won't see any difference in the output.

Comment: And yet the primitive float seems to work fine with that. That is `0.0f == -0.0f`. So the different behavior is only in `java.lang.Float`.

Comment: @ivant according to IEEE754, "The normal comparison operations, however, treat NaNs as unordered and compare −0 and +0 as equal" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Comment: @AndyTurner, yes I understand that. I'm just pointing out that in Java there is a difference in the behavior between the primitive type `float`, which conforms to IEEE754 in this regard and `java.lang.Float`, which does not. So just the difference in the bit representation is not enough to explain this.