# Why is the `n===0` used, as `-0===0` and `0===0` are both true?

Tags: javascript, typescript, comparison

```
function isNegZero(n) {
    n = Number( n );
    return (n === 0) && (1 / n === -Infinity);
}
```

I am reading the book `You don't know JS` and found this piece of code there. This is the function to check if the passes number is a **-0**. I failed to understand as to why the first condition in the comparison is mentioned as it is always going to be true (unless I am wrong in understanding it). Please help.

Comment: Maybe see [*Are +0 and -0 the same?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223359/are-0-and-0-the-same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s always going to be true *for zero*. You want `isNegZero(n)` to not only be false for `+0`, but also for any number that is not zero.

```
> let n = -Number.MIN_VALUE
> n === 0
false
> 1 / n === -Infinity
true
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value is the two comparisons '&&'ed together. Since it short circuits, if any number outside of 0 or -0 is passed, it will run the first comparison and then return false without ever needing to look at the second.