# How to use division in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, division

I want to divide a number in JavaScript and it would return a decimal value.

For example: `737/1070` - I want JavaScript to return `0.68`; however it keeps rounding it off and return it as `0`.

How do I set it to return me either two decimals place or the full results?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/YumpR/

Comment: In what context are you doing it? Javascript keeps the digits after the decimal when I do it http://jsfiddle.net/mrmikemccabe/ygqFN/

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Make one of those numbers a float.

```
737/parseFloat(1070)
```

or a bit faster:

```
737*1.0/1070
```

convert to 2 decimal places

```
Math.round(737 * 100.0 / 1070) / 100
```

Comment: `parseFloat` is for parsing from a string to a float.

Comment: a pair of pliers works just fine for banging in a nail, doesn't mean you should use it for such :)

Comment: Why not write `737.0 / 1070.0`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler because it might be stored in a variable.

Comment: In which case, the `* 1.0` is probably the way I'd do it.  I must have been taking a too literal interpretation of the question which was explicitly working with integer constants.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat `parseFloat(string)`, you spread bad usage of parseFloat to the whole internet

Comment: @JonathanLeffler +1 for `* 1.0`. Should we edit this answer to make it appear as the preferred solution? This answer is the first result for "javascript float division" search on my search engine.

Comment: @Jérôme: Best ask someone with a gold, or perhaps silver, badge in Javascript.  I don't have even a bronze badge over here.  I don't feel qualified to make that judgement call.

Answer (score 23):

`(737/1070).toFixed(2);` rounds the result to 2 decimals and returns it as a string. In this case the rounded result is `0.69` by the way, not `0.68`. If you need a real float rounded to 2 decimals from your division, use `parseFloat((737/1070).toFixed(2))`

[See also](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-mmrre8?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 3):

Also you can to use `[.toPrecision(n)]`, where `n` is (*total*) the number of digits. So `(23.467543).toPrecision(4)` => `23.47` or `(1241876.2341).toPrecision(8)` => `1241876.2`.

[See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision)

Comment: Be careful with `toPrecision`, it is a total number of digits, not the number of digits following the decimal (`.`). See this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337849/difference-between-tofixed-and-toprecision

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 let ans = 737/1070;
 console.log(ans.toFixed(2));
```

toFixed() function will do

Answer (score 0):

to get it to 2 decimal places you can: `alert( Math.round( 737 / 1070 * 100) / 100 )`

Answer (score 0):

with lodash:

```
const _ = require("lodash");
```

Use of _.divide() method

```
let gfg = _.divide(12, 5);
```

Printing the output

```
console.log(gfg)
2.4
```

[credit](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-divide-method/)