# After Addition two variables in javascript returning some garbage values

Tags: javascript

Hi I have two variables in JS Like:

```
var a = 223620.42
var b = 1200.1234
```

I am using Calculation Like:

```
var c = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
```

So the result should be = `224820.5434`

But it returning `224820.54340000002`

Please Suggest me what I am doing wrong here. Thanks in advance

Comment: The precision is fixed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: after decimal I want to show as it is not any precision..

Answer (score 0):

Just Round-off the last Values. See the Code Below:

```
var a = 223620.42
var b = 1200.1234
var c = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
var numb = c.toFixed(4);
alert(numb);
```

hope it will solve you problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using "toPrecision" method, and specify the desired length of the number.

`var a = 223620.42`
`var b = 1200.1234`
`var c = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);`

`c= c.toPrecision(3)`

Comment: it giving result c = 2.2e+5. I want 224820.5434

Comment: "toPrecision" will yield scientific notation if there are more integer digits in the number than the specified precision.

or you can go with "toFixed".
Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337849/difference-between-tofixed-and-toprecision