# Invoke .toPrecision() for scientific notation only

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I am using the `Math.exp` function with the `.toFixed()` method, but results that are expressed in scientific notation seem to ignore the method. Correct me if I am wrong, but I understand that `.toPrecision()` handles scientific notation better than does `.toFixed()`.

Is there a way to invoke the `.toPrecision()` method only if a result is expressed in scientific notation?

Answer (score 0):

`toPrecision` isn't better than `toFixed`, they're just different. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3337892/1378139.

If you'd like to invoke `toPrecision` only when `Math.exp(n)` would result in scientific notation, I guess you could exclude cases specifically, like:

```
var result = n !== 0 ? Math(n).toPrecision() : Math(n).toFloat();
```