# Rounding of alpha value in CSS color functions

Tags: css

In Chrome and Firefox (not tested in other browsers), `element.style.color = rgba(0, 0, 0, 49.6%)` resolves to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.494)` on my laptop. I expected `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.496)`.

Is this rounding behavior specified somewhere? And I can't find any related [WPT](https://github.com/web-platform-tests/wpt/blob/master/css/css-color/rgb-rounding-001.html).

Comment: Why does it matter? unit tests? Why does your RGBA has this weird value for *opacity*?

Comment: Yes, for unit tests of `jsdom/cssstyle`, which is an implementation of `CSSStyleDeclaration` for JavaScript.

Comment: Consider changing the test so it doesn't care about more than the [2nd number past the floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3337849/104380). (test only `0.49` or even better, round it to test for `0.5`)

Comment: Good idea but it won't work for the tests of the end user. `jsdom` should conform to specifications and browser behaviors. As a end user of a test environement, I would not want to expect a different value than what I can observe in browsers because my test environement is unable to serialize it as described in the specification.

Comment: You are being unreasonable. Tests should not be too harsh, especially in such scenarios like here where the human eye obviously cannot distinguish from alpha `0.49` and `0.5`. 
There no shame in this, but wisdom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [CSSOM specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#serialize-a-css-component-value):

> **<alphavalue>**
>
> If the value is internally represented as an integer between 0 and 255 inclusive (i.e. 8-bit unsigned integer), follow these steps:
>
> 1. Let *alpha* be the given integer.
> 2. If there exists an integer between 0 and 100 inclusive that, when multiplied with 2.55 and rounded to the closest integer (rounding up if two values are equally close), equals *alpha*, let *rounded* be that integer divided by 100.
> 3. Otherwise, let *rounded* be *alpha* divided by 0.255 and rounded to the closest integer (rounding up if two values are equally close), divided by 1000.
> 4. Return the result of serializing *rounded* as a <number>.
>    Otherwise, return the result of serializing the given value as a <number>.

Assuming that the color opacity is stored as a binary value:

```js
const alpha = Math.round(49.6 * 2.55) // 126
const integer = Math.round(alpha / 2.55) // 49
const hasInteger = Math.round(integer * 2.55) === alpha // false
const value = hasInteger
  ? integer / 100
  : Math.round(alpha / 0.255) / 1000
// 0.494
```

**Note on floating precision:**

Some values will be problematic regarding floating precision, eg. with `50` as opacity, alpha will be rounded to `127` instead of `128`, because in JavaScript `(50 * 2.55) === 127.49999999999999`.

A more accurate JavaScript implementation to serialize opacity would be:

```js
const alpha = Math.round((50 * 2.55).toPrecision(15)) // 128
const integer = Math.round(alpha / 2.55) // 50
const hasInteger = Math.round((integer * 2.55).toPrecision(15)) === alpha // true
const value = hasInteger
  ? integer / 100
  : Math.round(alpha / 0.255) / 1000
// 0.5
```

Comment: Huh, all the editor's drafts just vanished from drafts.csswg.org. That's bizarre. Hopefully just a temporary glitch.