# How to show numbers with 2 Decimal Places in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a calculator app to help with decimals and would like something to two decimal places like below:

```
number     output
------     -------
1          1.00
1.446      1.45
1.567      1.57
```

I have tried using toFixed(2) but I get an error as I'm using maths and not strings.

I've also tried using toPrecision(4) but I also get an error

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Vibration} from 'react-native';
import {useState} from 'react';
import { Entypo } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default function App() {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);
  const [currentNumber, setCurrentNumber] = useState('');
  const [lastNumber, setLastNumber] = useState('');

  const buttons = ['C', 'DEL', '/', 7, 8, 9, '*', 4, 5, 6, '-', 1, 2, 3, '+', 0, '.', '=']

  function calculator() {
    
    let lastArr = currentNumber[currentNumber.length-1];
    
    if(lastArr === '/' || lastArr === '*' || lastArr === '-' || lastArr === '+' || lastArr === '.') {
      setCurrentNumber(currentNumber)
      return
    }
    else {
      let result = eval(currentNumber).toString();
      setCurrentNumber(result)
      return
    }
  }

  function handleInput(buttonPressed) {
    if(buttonPressed  === '+' || buttonPressed === '-' || buttonPressed === '*' || buttonPressed === '/') {
      Vibration.vibrate(35);
      setCurrentNumber(currentNumber + buttonPressed)
      return
    }
    else if (buttonPressed === 1 || buttonPressed === 2 || buttonPressed === 3 || buttonPressed === 4 || buttonPressed === 5 ||
            buttonPressed === 6 || buttonPressed === 7 || buttonPressed === 8 || buttonPressed === 9 || buttonPressed === 0 || buttonPressed === '.' ) {
      Vibration.vibrate(35);
    }
    switch(buttonPressed) {
      case 'DEL':
        Vibration.vibrate(35);
        setCurrentNumber(currentNumber.substring(0, (currentNumber.length - 1)))
        return
      case 'C':
        Vibration.vibrate(35);
        setLastNumber('')
        setCurrentNumber('')
        return 
      case '=':
        Vibration.vibrate(35);
        setLastNumber(currentNumber + '=')
        calculator()
        return
    }
    setCurrentNumber(currentNumber + buttonPressed)
  }
```

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't tack on tags. See [ask].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your question it is not clear where you want to perform the conversion. However, this should get you on the right track.

Both [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed#return_value) and [`toPrecision()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision#return_value) return a string representing a number. It's clear that you can't use the string for further calculations. In order to do so, use [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat) to get the floating point number from the string.

```js
const floatingPointNumber = 1.567;
parseFloat(floatingPointNumber.toFixed(2));
parseFloat(floatingPointNumber.toPrecision(3));
```

Regarding `toFixed()` and `toPrecision()`, they actually perform the same operation but the first gives n decimal places while the latter gives n digits (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3337892/9378384)).

Comment: So in the end, I didn't use this code, but it did help me understand how to return the correct decimal places. I went with toFixed(2) on the 'result'. Thanks for commenting I really appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 3):

try this, may be helps you;

```
  function floatTwoDecFromString(value: string) {
    let newValue = value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');
    newValue =
      newValue.indexOf('.') !== -1
        ? newValue.slice(0, newValue.indexOf('.') + 3)
        : newValue;
    return newValue;
  }
```

Comment: Hey Danesh, thank you for commenting and providing some code. It was a little too complex for what I need, it turns out I only needed to add toFixed(2) to the 'result' which worked! I appreciate you spending time writing the function, keep up the good work!

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are trying to round and not just clip to decimal places. You could use `Math.round`. While it rounds to the nearest int, you could use this trick to round decimals:

```js
const roundToHundredths = num=>{
  let roundedNum = Math.round(num*100)/100
  // force 2 decimal places
  return roundedNum.toFixed(2);
}
```

Keep in mind that the value is now a string. Use `parseFloat` if other calculations have to be done

Comment: So in the end, I didn't use this code. I went with toFixed(2) on the 'result'. Thanks for commenting though, I really appreciate your help and the function was well written and clear!